# How can test I regular expressions using multiple RE engines?

Tags: regex, testing

How can I test the same regex against different regular expression engines?

Comment: @Lasse: how is this not constructive again?

Comment: @DanDascalescu This question is far too broad.

Comment: @chrylis: Edited. I've narrowed it down to testing the same regexp against multiple engines. Please see [@Shog9's comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222790/request-to-reopen-so-question-on-javascript-error-detection) on moderating tool recommendations as well.

Comment: @DanDascalescu You've completely misunderstood the original intent of the question but since I don't mind the question you're asking I don't see any point in editing it back.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: you might not have noticed that the question as you asked it, was closed as "not constructive" - see [its history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32282/revisions). My edit managed to reopen it after almost two years. You're welcome.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - you're making a fool of yourself here - this question  was asked in August 2008 - i.e. the first few days of SO's existence.  Running around down-voting answers and resurrecting questions which are now into their second half decade just makes you look slightly unhinged.

Comment: I'm glad wanting to have outdated information makes you look better, @Will. Of course, regular expressions are a thing of the past, and the upvoted that this question has received are no indication of interest in it.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I don't really care if it's re-opened or not; I made it community wiki long before it closed. Mainly I was looking for some other regex tools--I wasn't looking to test the same regex against different regex engines.  As I say, you've completely misunderstood the original intent of my question--regardless of whether or not the question should have been closed.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: I understood your question perfectly but in its original form, it didn't abide by the StackOverflow guidelines against soliciting tool recommendations.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The most powerful free online regexp testing tool is by far http://regex101.com/ - lets you select the RE engine (PCRE, JavaScript, Python), has a debugger, colorizes the matches, explains the regexp on the fly, can create permalinks to the regex playground.

Other online tools:

- http://regexpal.com/ - powered by the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) JavaScript library
- http://www.rubular.com/ - Ruby-based
- [Perl Regex Tutor](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/regextutor.shtml) - uses PCRE

Windows desktop tools:

- [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) - free Windows application
- [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) recommended by most, costs US$ 39.95

Jeff Atwood [wrote about regular expressions]( post:).

Other tools recommended by SO users include:

- http://www.txt2re.com/ Online free tool to generate regular expressions for multiple language  (@[palmsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions#4763) another thread)
- The Added Bytes [Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/) (@[GateKiller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions#4739) another thread)
- http://regexhero.net/ - The Online .NET Regular Expression Tester. Not free.

Comment: rubular is great, online and free...

Comment: I love regex coach - it does dynamic searching as you type. The only thing is that it seems like it's gone into hibernation.

Comment: http://www.txt2re.com/ tool nice to start learn regular expression.

Comment: http://regexhero.net/tester/ is a very nice tool

Comment: +1 for http://regexpal.com/ it's my favorite. :D

Comment: Quickrex is really good for eclipse: http://bastian-bergerhoff.com/eclipse/features/web/QuickREx/toc.html#installation

Comment: regexpal.com doesn't show the matching groups.  Worthless!

Answer (score 16):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Answer (score 10):

I use Expresso ([www.ultrapico.com](http://www.ultrapico.com/)).  It has a lot of nice features for the developer.  The Regulator used to be my favorite, but it hasn't been updated in so long and I constantly ran into crashes with complicated RegExs.

Comment: +1 Its all good now. Theres been an update in 09. Expresso 3.0, its pretty stable.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some for the Mac: (*Note: don't judge the tools by their websites*)

- [RegExhibit](http://homepage.mac.com/roger_jolly/software/) - My Favorite, powerful and easy
- [Reggy](http://code.google.com/p/reggy/) - Simple and Clean
- [RegexWidget](http://robrohan.com/2008/06/25/mac-os-x-regex-widget-update-17/) - A Dashboard Widget for quick testing

Comment: I will totally judge tools by their web sites, thank you very much. ;)

Answer (score 8):

If you are an Emacs user, the command `re-builder` lets you type an Emacs regex and shows on the fly the matching strings in the current buffer, with colors to mark groups. It's free as Emacs.

Answer (score 7):

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) is free, easy to use and looks nice.

Answer (score 6):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is a weapon of choice

Comment: Care to expand on that? What was your experience with the tool? Maybe mention it's Windows only and costs $40?

Answer (score 6):

I use the excellent and free [Rad Software Regular Expression Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/).

If you just want to write a regular expression, have a little help with the syntax and test the RE's matching and replacing then this fairly light-footprint tool is ideal.

Answer (score 3):

couple of eclipse plugins for those using eclipse,
http://www.brosinski.com/regex/

http://www.bastian-bergerhoff.com/eclipse/features/web/QuickREx/toc.html

Answer (score 3):

[Kodos](http://kodos.sourceforge.net/) of course. Cause it's Pythonic. ;)

Answer (score 2):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is great!!!

Answer (score 2):

I agree on RegExBuddy, but if you want free or when I'm working somewhere and not on my own system [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) is a great online (Flash) tool that has lots of pre-built regex segments to work with and does real-time pattern matching for your testing.

Comment: You could carry around a portable installation of RegexBuddy on a USB stick whenever you're not on your own system.

Comment: Flash tools suck. I'm glad RegExr is dead.

Answer (score 2):

In the standard **Python** installation there is a "Tools/scripts" directory containing **redemo.py**.

This creates an *interactive* Tkinter window in which you can experiment with regexs.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I preferred The Regex Coach for its simplistic layout, instantaneous highlighting and its price (free).

Every once in awhile though I run into an issue with it when trying to test .NET regular expressions.  For that, it turns out, it's better to use a tool that actually uses the .NET regular expression engine.  That was my whole reason to build [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/) last year.  It runs in Silverlight, and as such, runs off of the .NET Regex Class library directly.

Comment: RegexBuddy does *not* use the .NET regex engine. It uses the JGSoft engine, which is just as good, but with a slightly different feature set.  For example, it doesn't have .NET's "balanced matching" feature, but it does support unrestricted, variable-length lookbehind expressions--the only regex flavor besides .NET to do so.  As for Regex Hero, it's not really free; the online version is a demo that constantly nags you to buy the "professional" version.

Comment: @Alan - Thanks for the correction.  I wrote this answer a long time ago when Regex Hero was completely free and light on features.  I started charging for the professional version last December.

Answer (score 1):

Regexbuddy does all this. http://www.regexbuddy.com/

Answer (score 1):

see the accepted answer to this question: [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions#4741)

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to the vote of [Reggy](http://reggyapp.com/) for the Mac, gonna try out some of the other ones that Joseph suggested and upvote that post tomorrow when my limit gets reset.

Answer (score 1):

for online: http://regexpal.com/
for desktop: [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/)

Answer (score 1):

+1 For Regex Coach here.  Free and does the job really well.

http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/

Answer (score 1):

I am still a big [The Regulator](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/pages/tools-and-frameworks-by-roy-osherove.aspx) fan.
There are some stability problems but these can be fixed by disableing the Intellisense.  It gets mad with some expressions and typos in building an expression.

Would love it if [Roy Osherove](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/default.aspx) updated, but looks like he is busy with other things.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use this online one:
http://www.cuneytyilmaz.com/prog/jrx/
Of course, it'll be javascript regexp, but I've never yet done anything clever enough to notice the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the [Regular Expression Tester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2077).

It's a free firefox plugin, so always on!

Answer (score 1):

Also **[this regex plugin](http://myregexp.com/eclipsePlugin.html)** can be useful for **[eclipse](http://eclipse.org)** and **[idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)** users.

Answer (score 1):

I like http://regexhero.net/tester/ a lot

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Regex Master](http://alexandershapovalov.com/regular-expressions-tester-regex-master-74/) which is free and open source [regular expression tester](http://alexandershapovalov.com/regular-expressions-tester-regex-master-74/)

Answer (score 1):

This regex tester able to test javascript, php and python
http://www.piliapp.com/regex-tester/

Answer (score 0):

[RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) for testing with the Actionscript 3 (whichever standard that may be)

Comment: Flash-based tools suck. I'm glad RegExr is dead.

Answer (score 0):

How much is your time worth? Pay the $40 and get RegexBuddy. I did, and I even upgraded from 2.x version to 3.x. It has paid for itself many times over.

Answer (score -1):

RegExBuddy so far I concur with and endorse.