# Regex, how to select all items outside of selection group

Tags: regex

I'm a Regex noob and am pretty sure I'm not going about this in the most efficient way - wanted to get some advice.

I have a Regex expression `((\w+\b.*?){100}){1}`  which selects the first 100 words of my string, the length of which varies.

What I want is to select the entire string except for the first 100 words. 
Is there syntax I can add to my current expression to do this, or am I better off trying to directly select the rest of the text instead.

Also, if anyone has any good resources for improving my Regex knowledge, i'd be very appreciative. Thus far I've found http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as a side note, `{1}` is just noise and can be omitted.

Comment: `\w+\b` does not describe a word in the common sense as `\w` does not match hyphens. So `foo-bar` would be two “`\w` words”.

Comment: I've found http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to be very helpful.

Comment: Also, `\w` only matches ascii characters, `"café"` wouldn't be matches (at least, not the `é`).

Comment: @Bart Kiers: This depends on the regex flavor. In .NET, `\w` matches Unicode letters/digits/underscore, for example.

Comment: Also also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing-tools) about regex testing tools.

Comment: @Tim, ah, didn't know that. But even without some Unicode-flag?

Comment: @Bart: In .NET, yes; in Python, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this, you can refer to everything else as group 3 noted as `$3`
This one will treat hyphenated words as one word.

`(\w+(-\w+|\b).*?){100}(.*)`

[Regex training Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html)

Comment: "depending on your processing environment"

Comment: @belisarius Yes... *your milaige may vary, taxes, fees, handling and points not included.*

Comment: @belisarius But of course...with white on white font colour too.  ;o)