# preg_match some characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need an regex to my `preg_match()`, it should preg (allow) the following characters:

String can contain only letters, numbers, and the following punctuation marks:

- full stop (.)
- comma (,)
- dash (-)
- underscore (_)

I have no idea , how it can be done on regex, but I think there is a way!

Comment: If only there was a way to find out more on preg syntax.. :P

Comment: Yes, this can be done. See the manual on http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php or some of the tools http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing-tools

Comment: Look what I found: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}.,_-]*$
```

will match a string that contains only (Unicode) letters, digits or the "special characters" you mentioned. `[...]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), meaning "one of the characters contained here". You'll need to use the `/u` Unicode modifier for this to work:

```
preg_match(`/^[\p{L}\p{N}.,_-]*$/u', $mystring);
```

If you only care about ASCII letters, it's easier:

```
^[\w.,-]*$
```

or, in PHP:

```
preg_match(`/^[\w.,-]*$/', $mystring);
```