# php regex to match outside of html tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

I am making a preg_replace on html page. My pattern is aimed to add surrounding tag to some words in html. However, sometimes my regular expression modifies html tags. For example, when I try to replace this text:

```
<a href="example.com" alt="yasar home page">yasar</a>
```

So that `yasar` reads `<span class="selected-word">yasar</span>` , my regular expression also replaces yasar in alt attribute of anchor tag. Current `preg_replace()` I am using looks like this:

```
preg_replace("/(asf|gfd|oyws)/", '<span class=something>${1}</span>',$target);
```

How can I make a regular expression, so that it doesn't match anything inside a html tag?

Comment: @MarcB for once, I think this is a valid regex problem. It's hard to easily do what the OP wants with a DOM parser. He just needs to know how not to match words that are within quotes.

Comment: @Xeon: still a bad idea. Use dom/xpath to get the textnodes, then manipulate them individually. It's the only 100% reliable method to make sure you're dealing only with "relevant" text and not some wonky subchunk of a badly formed tag that matched.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use an assertion for that, as you just have to ensure that the searched words occur somewhen after an `>`, or before any `<`. The latter test is easier to accomplish as lookahead assertions can be variable length:

```
/(asf|foo|barr)(?=[^>]*(<|$))/
```

See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for a nice explanation of that assertion syntax.

Comment: Yada yada, silly bobince answer... -- Yes, that's not quite correct. This regex only works for XML/XHTML, and only without CDATA edge cases etc. But even in real-world HTML you don't see angle brackets in attributes. So, workable as basic solution.

Comment: I am getting `Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 27` when trying to run your regexp. Maybe you missed something?

Comment: Try again. Code edited since. (There was a `?<=` where the `?=` should have been.)

Comment: seems like it only change one string multiple times. for example, I have a string "....AAA...BBB...AAA...", only AAA will be changed, but not BBB. why is that?

Comment: mario, how to get in touch with u? i want to use ur solution, but know almost nothing about it

Comment: @likeforex.com: We don't do personal support here, and SO is not a forum; discussing a different topic in between is not provided for. Especially if inquiries are that vague. ("What have you tried?"). I have no clue what you want. -- For help see also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: that's cool. the thing is when I tried to use your solution. it can only replace one string with a link, while a glossary can have a few different links.

Comment: for example i have a text string like AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE F G H, i want to replace to <a href="link1">AAA</a> BBB CCC <a href="link2">DDD</a> EEE F G H. your solution only works for one link! Is that right?

Comment: @likeforex.com: Yes it only works for one link. No, it cannot be fixed.

Comment: this is what i have. the terms are from a loop and tried to replace whatever in the loop but not inside a link. preg_replace("~($term)(?=[^>]*(<|$))~i", $newterm, $html)

Comment: is it possible to look for anything not inside <a href=...>...</a> in the lookaround part?

Answer (score 9):

Yasar, resurrecting this question because it had another solution that wasn't mentioned.

Instead of just checking that the next tag character is an opening tag, this solution skips all `<full tags>`.

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html, here is the regex:

```
<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|word1|word2|word3
```

Here is a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/sF4tP4). In code, it looks like this:

```
$target = "word1 <a skip this word2 >word2 again</a> word3";
$regex = "~<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|word1|word2|word3~";
$repl= '<span class="">\0</span>';
$new=preg_replace($regex,$repl,$target);
echo htmlentities($new);
```

Here is an [online demo](http://ideone.com/fCL1ex) of this code.

**Reference**

1. [How to match pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)
2. [How to match a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Answer (score 0):

This might be the kind of thing that you're after: http://snipplr.com/view/3618/
In general, I'd advise against such. A better alternative is to strip out all HTML tags and instead rely on BBcode, such as:

```
[b]bold text[b] [i]italic text[i]
```

However I appreciate that this might not work well with what you're trying to do.

Another option may be HTML Purifier, see: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Answer (score 0):

From top of my mind, this should be working:

```
echo preg_replace("/<(.*)>(.*)<\/(.*)>/i","<$1><span class=\"some-class\">$2</span></$3>",$target);
```

But, I don't know how safe this would be. I am just presenting a possibility :)