# PHP: wrap (all) needle with a html element in a string haystack

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

for my autosuggest functionality I need to colorize the excerpts in suggestions...so..

if I search something like
"sa"
the suggester gives me thefolowing

Samsung
satire
sata
e-sata
...

Now what I'd like from my function is that it highlights - wraps the "sa" needle (all occuracies) qith a desired html tag.

like
**Sa**msung
**sa**tire
**sa**ta
e-**sa**ta

- It should be utf8 safe
- It should preserve the capitalization
- it should ignore HTML

On the PHP site I found a function that does the replacement and keeps the capitalization... I modified it so it's utf8 friendly...

```
function ext_str_ireplace($findme, $replacewith, $text) { 
    // Replaces $findme in $subject with $replacewith 
    // Ignores the case and do keep the original capitalization by using $1 in $replacewith 
    // Required: PHP 5 

    $rest = $text; 

    $result = ''; 

    while (mb_stripos($rest, $findme) !== false) { 
      $pos = mb_stripos($rest, $findme); 

      // Remove the wanted string from $rest and append it to $result 
      $result .= mb_substr($rest, 0, $pos); 
      $rest = mb_substr($rest, $pos, mb_strlen($rest)-$pos); 

      // Remove the wanted string from $rest and place it correctly into $result 
      $result .= mb_ereg_replace('$1', mb_substr($rest, 0, mb_strlen($findme)), $replacewith); 
      $rest = mb_substr($rest, mb_strlen($findme), mb_strlen($rest)-mb_strlen($findme)); 
    } 

    // After the last match, append the rest 
    $result .= $rest; 

    return $result; 
}
```

It works great...like

```
ext_str_ireplace("sa", "<b>sa</b>", "Samsung");
```

untill I pass some html code into it

```
$text= '<p class="red">A client is an application or system that accesses a service made available by a server. </p>';
ext_str_ireplace("cl", "<b>cl</b>", $text);
```

of course the function will replace the "cl" string in "

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891771/php-regex-to-match-outside-of-html-tags

Comment: Thanks mario.... I used the solution from the answer bellow and added something from your link ........+ I added utf8 flag, to be safe..... return preg_replace('/('.$expression.')(?=[^>]*(<|$))/iu', '<b>$1</b>', $text);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   function keywords($text, $words)
    {
        if (sizeof($words) == 1)
        {
            $expression = preg_quote($words[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($words as $key => $word)
            {
                $words[$key] = preg_quote($word);
            }
            $expression = implode('|', $words);
        }   
        return preg_replace('/('.$expression.')(?=[^>]*(<|$))/iu', '<strong>$1</strong>', $text);
    }
```

Usage:

```
keywords('Samsung', array('sa', 'ng'));
```

Comment: How does this solve my problem? It is not utf8 safe + it doesn't skip html markup

Comment: Ok, I used your solution and added an assertion as mario suggested in another answer..+ I added a u flag for utf safe...........return preg_replace('/('.$expression.')(?=[^>]*(<|$))/iu', '<b>$1</b>', $text);