# Wrap substrings in <strong> tags without creating nested tags while replacing

Tags: php, html, arrays, preg-replace

I have an array of words which I am using to highlight words in a string, some of the words however might appear as part of a phrase, and so I would like the phrase to take precedence over the single word in the highlight:

For example:

```
$seo = ['apple', 'apple tree', 'orchard'];

$description = "In my orchard I have a large Apple Tree";
```

Desired effect:

```
In my <strong>orchard</strong> I have a large <strong>Apple Tree</strong>
```

In my own first attempt, I looped through the array running `preg_replace()` against the string, but I am getting nested highlights like this `<strong><strong>Apple</strong> Tree</strong>`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't use a loop to replace each word individually, but a regex alternatives list `(foo|bar|thingy)`.

```
  $rx_words = implode("|", array_map("preg_quote", $words));
  $text = preg_replace("/\b($rx_words)\b/i",
```

(Actually that preg_quote misses the second param, but as long as you don't have forward slashes in the keywords, it'll work.)

Then you can also make it safer with an assertion:

```
  $text = preg_replace("/(?<!<strong>)\b($rx_words)\b/i",
```

So it will ignore words that are already wrapped. That's just a workaround, but quite often sufficient.

Comment: See also [php regex to match outside of html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891771/php-regex-to-match-outside-of-html-tags) for the followup problem.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? I have no idea on how to implement it, and it seems incomplete to my application?  $seo=array(); $description="In my orchard I have a large Apple Tree";

Comment: Replace your foreach with the two lines above. Obviously the preg_replace still needs the two params you already have in that function.

Comment: Works quite well when I test it. Maybe you should show what you've actually tried?

Comment: preg_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given

Comment: Well, you forgot something then. Edit your question, show current code. I'm not editing it for you.

Comment: Not asking you to edit for me, but posting code without explanation is really not that helpful.  It is the understanding that is required.  Appreciate your help, but an incomplete example without explanation just complicates further.  I have studied the php.net site, but if you find yourself in a position where you are not really sure what is required.... :/

Comment: I gave you an extensive answer. Your problem is that you certainly didn't write the `highlightsWords()` function yourself, found it elsewhere. And now you're asking on SO for another copy&pasteable fix. That's not what this site is for. -- And since you don't even show what you've tried, I get the impression that you didn't even try to understand your existing code, the given answer, or reasonably tried to apply it. Looks like gimme the codez.

Comment: gimme the codez its not, I studied and learnt and as you pointed out from the outset, I took the wrong approach looping through my array and then applying a replace on a match.  Try remember back to when you was learning..  arrays,imploding them,preg_match and then using them all together in the right combination, jump down off your horse and maybe even consider using a comment or two in your examples.

Comment: Yeah well sorry. But I can't explain anything about it. It's way too trivial to me, as there's really no ambiguity on what and how to replace it in the function, even just going by the variable names. Hencewhy I've asked you twice to show what you've tried. Edit your question.

Comment: So why answer the question to begin with?  I see from further study based on your 'pointers' that it would hightlight "apple" dropping "apple tree" so, an incorrect approach anyway. Still to too trivial for you?

Comment: So, what do you want now? Do you want further explanations? Or do you want a code snippet that you can copy & paste after all?

Comment: $text = preg_replace("/(?<!<strong>)\b($rx_words)\b/i", "<b>$0</b>", $string); this works great! for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your array of replaceable words by length descending before calling `preg_replace()`.  This will ensure that longer strings are matched before shorter words and therefore avoid the nested replacement problem that you were encountering.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AFke0))

```
$seo = ['apple', 'apple tree', 'orchard'];
$description = "In my orchard I have a large Apple Tree";

array_multisort(array_map('strlen', $seo), SORT_DESC, $seo);

var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '#\b(?:' . implode('|', $seo) . ')\b#i',
        '<strong>$0</strong>',
        $description
    )
);
```