# Replacing words in a block of HTML code without changing the HTML

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

Let's say I have block of HTML where I want to do a find and replace on the content before echoing out to the screen.

How do I ensure I don't change the HTML but just change the content (in PHP).

For example, if I had this:

```
<div class='Hello'>Hello</div>
```

and I wanted to replace all the 'Hello' words in the content with 'Hi' I would want to get this result:

```
<div class='Hello'>Hi</div>
```

At the moment I am using preg_replace, e.g.

```
$new_code = preg_replace(array("/Hello/"), array("Hi"), $code);
```

But this would give me the result

```
<div class='Hi'>Hi</div>
```

Comment: Why not `array("/>Hello/"), array(">Hi")` ?

Comment: You want to replace just `Hello` to `Hi`?

Comment: This is just an example. The content will be much longer than this and the word I want to replace may not necessarily follow a closing bracket.

Comment: I think maybe I need a regular expression that doesn't match anything between a < and a >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex to find text in HTML use a DOM parser instead:

You could use [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/DOMDocument) but be careful it will do strange things with partial HTML, but here's an example to get you going:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<html><body><p>Hello</p></body></html>");

$els = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach ( $els as $el ) {

    if (preg_replace("/Hello/","Hi",$el->nodeValue))
    {
        $el->nodeValue =preg_replace("/Hello/","Hi",$el->nodeValue);
    }

} 

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

or [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) may meet your needs:

Example from site:

```
$html = str_get_html('<div class='Hello'>Hello</div>');

$html->find('div', 0)->innertext = 'Hi';

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking forward to change from `Hello` to `Hi` then,

```
$new_code = preg_replace(array("/\>Hello/"), array(">Hi"), $code);
```

Comment: This is just an example. The content will be much longer than this and the word I want to replace may not necessarily follow a closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this assertion (see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891771/php-regex-to-match-outside-of-html-tags)) to only match text that occurs between `>` and `<`:

```
$new_code = preg_replace(array("/(Hello)(?=[^>]*(<|$))/"), array("Hi"), $code);
```

Comment: This is just an example. The content will be much longer than this and the word I want to replace may not necessarily follow a closing bracket.

Comment: I edited my answer. Is that closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried this but the problem is if you have: <p><a class='Hello'>Hello</a></p> then this matches both Hellos as they appear between the > < of the p tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<?PHP

$html = '<div class="HeLLo" id="HEllO">Hello how to say "hEllo"
         for heLlo world in a helLo world of hellO</div>';

echo preg_replace('/(hello)(?![^>](\s*\w+=".*")*\s*>)/i', "Hi", $html);

?>
```