# Regex: Match start of string after (*SKIP)(*F)

Tags: php, regex

The expression `<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|(\/|\s|^|\()(Dakota Ridge.*?)(,|\.|\s|\b|\)|<)` matches `Dakota Ridge` in the string `The Dakota Ridge Trail is open.` as expected.

If I wrap `Dakota Ridge Trail` in HTML tags, however, the string is no longer matched: `The <b>Dakota Ridge Trail</b> is open.`

I thought the `^` alternative would assert that the string is anchored at the start since `(*SKIP)` prevents the engine from backtracking past that point but apparently it doesn't work that way.

How can I modify this expression to match if the string is anchored at the first position after a skipped and failed match?

Edit to clarify: The purpose of `<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)` is to skip HTML tags that could potentially contain the pattern within.

Comment: Not sure what exact requirements you have, but [`<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(Dakota Ridge.*?)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/vKP1ZD/1/) will do better than the current pattern. Yours consumes `<` with `|<` (it must be removed) and there is no *leading* `\b` alternative.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891771/php-regex-to-match-outside-of-html-tags may be it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Using `\b` may be just what I'm looking for. I need to test more use cases, but so far so good. The only preceding character that needs to make the match fail is `!` but I can solve that with a negative lookbehind: `<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|\b((?<!!)Dakota Ridge.*?)\b`

Comment: It isn't matched because you are missing `>` in your first group while in the last group you have `<` this seems to be inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not match the second occurrence because the substring you want to match is preceded with a `>` that is consumed and discarded after SKIP-FAIL does its job. That means there is no way for the `(\/|\s|^|\()` pattern to match the empty space before `Dakota` as it is not `/`, nor a whitespace, start of string or `(`.

Since you have a `\b` word boundary in the trailing position, you may use it in the leasing position, too, and further restrict the context with lookarounds (e.g. lookbehind).

For the current scenario, the following will do:

```
<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(Dakota Ridge.*?)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vKP1ZD/1/).

**Details**

- `<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)` - match `<`, then 0+ chars other than `>` and then a `>`, and discard the match keeping the regex index right at the end of the match
- `|` - or
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(Dakota Ridge.*?)` - Group 1: `Dakota Ridge`, and then any 0+ chars (other than line break chars) as few as possible, p to the first
- `\b` - word boundary.