# PHP preg_replace words in array but skip links (href)

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, replace, preg-replace

I'm working on some code to replace words inside the WordPress content for links. For example: the word "example" needs to be replaced for a text link: `<a href="'.$site.'/glossary/example/" class="glossary-link">example</a>`.

I've got this working with the following code:

```
function word_replace($text){
    $site = esc_url( home_url() );

    $replace = array(
        'example' => '<a href="'.$site.'/glossary/example/" class="glossary-link">example</a>',
        'word' => '<a href="'.$site.'/glossary/word/" class="glossary-link">word</a>',
    );

    $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);

    return $text;
}
```

The only issue is that words inside a href="" attribute also get replaced and this breaks the HTML. How do I avoid words from being replaced inside a href="" attribute or inside a class="" attribute? What regex do I need to skip these attributes? A piece of example code would be a big help :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php regex to match outside of html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891771/php-regex-to-match-outside-of-html-tags). If you want to do this by regex, I'd recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23667869/5527985)

Comment: Hi @bobblebubble, thanks for answering my question and the link to this solution. I'm actually looking for the opposite of this answer. In this comment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7891998/7735516) everything is being skipped except for links (HTML a tags). I would like to replace any words within an array inside the WordPress content ($text) but skip the HTML a tags. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You meant outside tags, right? See [this at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GLMmMi/1/). It matches `foo` and `bar` if not `<`inside`>`.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS OUT**

```
$site = 'http://example.com';
$html = '<a href="'.$site.'text">Link</a>';
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$node = $nodes[0];
$node->setAttribute('href', 'page.html');
echo $dom->saveHTML($node);
```