# Replace a string inside quotes that avoid tag attributes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace only text between string inside quotes, i want to ignore text inside tag attributes. I want to add some tags to replacements.

I have:

```
This text is in <font style="color:#f00;">red</font>. This text have "quotes and some spaces", more text inside "quotes"
```

Result I wants:

```
This text is in <font style="color:#f00;">red</font>. This text have "<b>quotes and some spaces</b>", more text inside "<b>quotes</b>"
```

Is important to ignore text inside tag attributes. I want to avoid match "color:#f00;" -> "**color:#f00;**"

Thanks for your great support.

Comment: A duplicate of [php regex to match outside of html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891771/php-regex-to-match-outside-of-html-tags)

Comment: Problem here is that we need to ignore the content inside attributes of tags, we need only match text content inside quotes in a string, not tags.

Comment: Right, that is why it is a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
$str = 'This text is in <font style="color:#f00;">red</font>. This text have "quotes and some spaces", more text inside "quotes"';

echo htmlentities(preg_replace('/"([a-zA-Z\s]*)"/', '<b>$1</b>', $str));
```

Result:

```
This text is in <font style="color:#f00;">red</font>. This text have <b>quotes and some spaces</b>, more text inside <b>quotes</b>
```

The regex that allow only letters and spaces do the job: /"([a-zA-Z\s]*)"/