# how protect wordpress comment form from runnig scripts?

Tags: security, wordpress-theming, comments

Recentrly we developred a custom theme for our Wordpress website,
and I've used native comment Wordpress system that the code is something like below.
the question is how could we protect comment form from xss attack? it seems that scripts like `<script>alert('hi');</script>` runs simply on comments form.
any idea?

thank you.

```
<section>
    <main>
        <div class="comment-area">

            <h2 class="comment-title -pb-20">
            number of comments:  <span><?php echo get_comments_number(); ?></span>           
            </h2>     
                

            <div  class="comment-form">
                <h3>Insert you comment here please.</h3>
                <?php 
                    $arg = array(
                        'title_reply'          => '',
                        'comment_notes_before' => '',
                        'label_submit'         => 'submmit',
                        
                    );
                    comment_form($arg);  
                ?>
            </div>

           <?php if (have_comments()) : ?>
                <div class="comment-list">
                    <h1>all comments</h1>  
                    <ul>
                        <?php

                            $args = array(
                                'style'             => 'ul',
                                'callback'          => null,
                                'end-callback'      => null,
                                'type'              => 'comment',
                                'reply_text'        => 'reply',
                                'page'              => '',
                                'per_page'          => '',
                                'avatar_size'       => 32,
                                'reverse_top_level' => true,    
                                'reverse_children'  => '',
                                'format'            => 'html5',
                                'echo'              => true,
                            ); 


                            wp_list_comments($args);
                        ?>
                    </ul> 
                </div>

                <div class="comments-pagination">
                    <?php if(get_comment_pages_count() > 1  &&  get_option('page_comments')) : ?>
                    <div>
                        <?php previous_comments_link('prev');  ?>
                    </div> 
                    <div>
                        <?php next_comments_link('next');  ?>
                    </div> 
                    <?php  endif; ?>
                    
                </div><!-- .comments-pagination -->


            <?php endif; ?>


        </div>
    </main>
</section>
```

Comment: Can't you simplify the process and just use an `<input>` tag hooking up a `change` event  to filter `<script>` or all `html` tags?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to do that!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I think this method is client-side protection. how about server-side? is it any way to accomplish it with PHP code?

Comment: Ah yes of course, it's much better and actually secure (client side protection gives a false sense of security) so you can just do what you'd do client-side in validating data but do it server-side instead right before deciding whether you want to process data. For example if you can have Regular Expressions in PHP, then don't match any recognized tags - or just `<script>` tags if you want.                                       Edit: see the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891771/php-regex-to-match-outside-of-html-tags and see if that's helpful.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. but you know, it does not seem that the default commenting system in WordPress gives me any HTML tag to be able to validate, sanitize it. that's why I asked this question. BTW thank you very much for your help and time bro.

Comment: Do you send your input to the server or something before allowing posted comments to be displayed publicly first? I'm saying you should sanitize it there and decide right there (server-side) whether it should be posted or not.

Comment: uhm, maybe there is a filter in Wordpress, I should search for it. thanks for the clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'sanitize_comment' );
function sanitize_comment( $comment_text ) {
    $comment_text = sanitize_text_field($comment_text);
    return $comment_text;
}
```