# Using htmlspecialchars except <b></b> and <i></i>

Tags: php, html

I want to use htmlspecialchars on user's textarea, but I want him to allow to use bold and italic. How can I not use htmlspecialchars on those tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the better-safe-than-sorry method. That is you first apply [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), and then very selectively undo it / whitelist your two tags:

```
 $html = htmlspecialchars($html);
 $html = preg_replace('#&lt;(/?[bi])&gt;#', '<$1>', $html);
```

That works only when those tags only contain those exact two strings, no extra attributes. No safety or consistency concerns with that however (except that this short version doesn't assert balanced tags, ooops).

If you need more complex rules, then [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is what you should look out for.

Comment: @mario: If you leave <b> it will make bold all text below.

Comment: Yes, you need to make it more clever then. `'#&lt;([bi])&gt;(.*?)&lt;/\1&gt;#', '<$1>$2</$1>', $html);`

Comment: @mario: This example doesn't work... And how do you know this stuff? Maybe you could suggest any tutorials? Because it seems very useful.

Comment: Regular expressions are sort of a programming language on their own. The [syntax list in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) is okay, but http://regular-expressions.info/ is more introductory. Also check out some of the tools [Open source regexbuddy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) and [online guis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing-tools).

Answer (score -2):

I like to use the tinyMCE jquery plugin for this kind of thing.

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php

hope that helps.

Comment: What does this have to do with jquery?

Comment: Doesn't have to be just found it a nice solution.