# Breaking a given HTML code using Reg Exp

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone help me with a quick regex problem?

I have the following HTML:

```
555 Some Street Name<BR />
New Providence VA 22901-1311<BR />
United States<BR />
```

The first row is always the Street

Second row is City (which can have spaces) space State Abbv. space Zip hyphen 4 digit zip

Third row is the Country.

I need to break the HTML into a variable each. Can anyone provide a quick regex?

Edit: Maybe I wasn't clear. I need the following:
Street address, City, State, Zip, 4Digit Zip, Country as individual variables.

Comment: is it in different lines? Then you can just strip the tags and take it.

Comment: What is "Zip" and "4Digit Zip" in this case? An example would be nice. (I come from germany, and I am unaccustomed to this format).

Comment: To construct a regex see also [open source regexbuddy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [regexp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: the $zip in this case would be 22901 and 4 digit zip would be $fourZip = 1311

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/665923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
555 Some Street Name<BR />
New Providence VA 22901-1311<BR />
United States<BR />
```

ok, for the first part, let's split the lines

```
$array = explode('<BR />', $address);
```

now you need to get the informations from the second line to be parsed as well...

```
$array[1] = New Providence VA 22901-1311;
```

$tmp = explode(' ', $array[1]);

and all you need now is to set everything in the correct variable names

```
$fullZip = array_pop($tmp);
$zipArray = explode('-',$fullZip);
$zip = $zipArray[0];
$Digitzip = $zipArray[1];
$state = array_pop($tmp);
$providence = implode($tmp);
$country = $array[2];
$street = $array[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't even require regular expressions. You can split the diefferent lines using `explode("<BR />",...)`. First line is Street, Last line is country. The middle line can be split using `substr()`, as you know that the last 4 characters are the 4 digit ZIP, the 6 characters before them are the ZIP followed by a hyphen and the 3 characters before them are the state followed by a space. So the numbers of characters of the segments (counted from the end of the line) is constant.

Comment: I like this. If I have to run the same thing on 100,000 rows of data, would substr still be better then preg_match?

Comment: Definitly. I don't have numbers right now, but substr should run much faster than preg_match

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regex.

```
$htmlStr = '555 Some Street Name<BR />New Providence VA 22901-1311<BR />United States<BR />';
```

[**Live example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BtM0Bb)

Note, however, that for more complicated HTML parsing, [regexes are not the tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/104999).

Comment: Wrong programming language! ;-)

Comment: @Armin oops, I feel stupid now, I'm used to answering JS questions haha. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = explode('<BR />', $address);
```

This is the easiest way, just split the string by the `<br />`-tags. If you can avoid regular expressions, you should do, cause they are not as performant than simple string operations like an [explode](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I need the following:
Street address, City, State, Zip, 4Digit Zip, Country as individual variables.

Comment: You just need to work with the $array[1], cause [0] and [2] contains already, what you want. You could use `strpos` in combination with `substr`, and split this part by the "VA" string.