# php regex ctype

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to see if the $input ONLY contained alphabetic characters or white spaces also need one to check if $numInput ONLY contained numeric characters or white spaces AND one combined so:

```
$alphabeticOnly = 'abcd adb';
$numericOnly = '1234 567';
$alphabeticNumeric = 'abcd 3232';
```

So in all of the above examples alphabetic, numeric, whitespace are allowed ONLY NO symbols.

How can I get those 3 diffrent regular expression?

Comment: See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you

```
if (!preg_match('/^[\sa-zA-Z]+$/', $alphabeticOnly){
    die('alpha match fail!');
}

if (!preg_match('/^[\s0-9]+$/', $numericOnly){
    die('numeric match fail!');
}

if (!preg_match('/^[\sa-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $alphabeticNumeric){
    die('alphanumeric match fail!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty basic

```
/^[a-z\s]+$/i - letter and spaces
/^[\d\s]+$/ - number and spaces
/^[a-z\d\s]+$/i - letter, number and spaces
```

Just use them in `preg_match()`

Answer (score 1):

In order to be unicode compatible, you should use:

```
/^[\pL\s]+$/      // Letters or spaces
/^[\pN\s]+$/      // Numbers or spaces
/^[\pL\pN\s]+$/   // Letters, numbers or spaces
```

Comment: @MikeVercoelen: To be able to match other characters than ASCII, such as `ç ñ é è â`. Have a look at http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/