# regex to replace filepath to just filename in a string using php

Tags: php, regex, dom

I've got a css string like this :

```
$string = "div#test {background: url(images/test.gif); width:100px; } div#test2 {background: url(../images/test2.gif); } ";
```

Basically I want to able to replace everything between url () to just the filename. So that it eventually looks like :

```
$string = "div#test {background: url(test.gif); width:100px; } div#test2 {background: url(test2.gif); } ";
```

Sort of like applying basename but for relative urls and for all such instances.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What does this have to do with [dom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom)? And did you investigate anything yet? -- For regex construction there are some tools, see [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

EDIT: I fixed the regex

```
<?php 

$string = "div#test {background: url(images/test.gif); width:100px; } div#test2 {background: url(../images/test2.gif); } ";
$output = preg_replace('/([\.\w\/]*\/)/', '', $string);

var_dump($output);
string(93) "div#test {background: url(test.gif); width:100px; } div#test2 {background: url(test2.gif); } "
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

taking for granted that u have the file name stored in a variable, you could use

```
$string = preg_replace('~url(.+)~', 'url(' . $filename . ')', $string);
```

www.regular-expressions.info is a good source if u want to learn regular expressions

Comment: Well, no i don't have the filename stored.

Comment: Go with jack's solution. Alternatively you may have to write 3-4 lines of code to get the filename first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have to match several div's in one string you could do something like this:

```
preg_replace(
    '@(.+url\()/?([^/]+/)*([^)]+)(\).+)@',
    '\\1\\3\\4',
    'div#test {background: url(images/test.gif); width:100px; }'
);
```

This also allows you to pass an array with multiple strings to replace

Comment: And lets so I also wanted to filter out any absolute URL components (http/https/ftp), could I do an OR operation with (ht|f)tp(s|):\/\/)