# need a regular expression in javascript which allows text having special character * in the begining of input data

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am new to regex. I need a regex for JavaScript code that allows special character * in the beginning of text input, but not anywhere else in the text.

example : it should allow   ***text**, 
          it should not allow  ***text*abcd**

I would need a similar regex for PHP as well.

I have tried using "/^\s*/", but this doesn't work. Anyways I dont have anyidea of regex. I have started learning it.

Thanks
Dora

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: Obviously this question needs some more (nearly identical) answers, 7 isn't enough. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of learning how to use regex is knowing when you don't need it. In this case a solution without regex would suffice, for PHP:

```
if (strrpos($str, '*') > 0) {
  // invalid position of *
}
```

For JavaScript:

```
if (str.lastIndexOf('*') > 0) {
    // invalid position for *
}
```

It basically finds the last position of the special character; if it appears in the string and is not the first character, the code inside the condition gets executed.

Comment: Tempted to give an extra downvote for downvote whining. Anyway, this wasn't asked for. It's a tag rot contribution, and not useful for the Javascript case requested above. And there's the impression this answer is just due to anti-regex or microoptimization memes.

Comment: While I see @mario's point, I think it's a good alternative. Why regex when you don't have to? However, I think you mean "*A solution **without** regex...*"

Comment: @mario ah right, forgot the JavaScript case; this is not anti-regex, but just how I normally deal with string problems.

Comment: @Bracketworks right, just reworded the first sentence ;-) thanks!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I was in great hurry and your answer sorted my problem

Comment: @mario After adding the JS variant, which I forgot, I fail to see how this is not what was asked for: a condition that determines whether a character - if present - only appears at the start of a string. And i don't understand the tag rot classification either.

Comment: Yes, you solved OPs immediate problem. It satisfies the plzsendtehcodez. Yet the question will show up in Google as [regex] question, but with a [strpos] answer (well, if it wasn't for the other on-topic answers, of course). I fail to see why this isn't tag rot. You don't know if the next asker tripping over this page won't in fact need to assert a bit more than just the first character.

Answer (score 3):

```
^\*?[^*]+$
```

- The `^` means match from the start of the string
- The `\*?` optionally matches a `*` (the `?` means zero-or-one matches)
- The `[^*]+` matches one-or-more characters that are not `*`
- The `$` means that the match has to end at the very end of the string, to make sure there aren't any extra `*`s

This can be used in [PHP](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) and [Javascript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

Answer (score 2):

Should get you there.

```
^\*[^\*]+$    // forces the first asterisk

^\*?[^\*]+$   // allows the first asterisk
```

Answer (score 1):

if I am understanding well, I think that you should just scape the * like this \*, also remember to write this \\* in case that you are writting the regex in a string

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
/^(\*)?[^*]+/
```

The `^` symbol means `in the beginning`

Comment: This matches `*text*abcd` (which is explicitly disallowed).

Comment: This expression *requires* an `*` at the beginning, which I don't think is what is wanted. It says "allows for" not "requires". I suppose it can be interpreted either way.

Comment: Well, this is what I understood. The question is misconceived

Comment: yes the input having * in the beginning shall be allowed. But it is not compulsary to have * in the begining.

Answer (score 0):

Give this expression a shot:

```
^.?[^*]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/^\*[^\*]+$/g
```

Here is an example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uRhc/).