# how to use php explode or pregmatch in this text

Tags: php, preg-match, explode

Can anyone help me how to split /explode verse format to 3 parts?

The condition should be as follows.

the second and 3rd part must be seperated by a colon. so for example in Gen 1:1

it must be seperated as

```
[0] = Gen
[1] = 1
[2] = 1
```

it is delimited by a space (or many space to make it user friendly) and by a colon

secondly, in verses with numeric in front is a problem because user can type it as

1 Cor 1:1 and they can also type it as 1Cor 1:1

in either case I want [1] and [2] to be split by a colon and the remaining parts will be trimmed all space and became the [0] value.

is this possible? Because I am thinking of using only one text box for searching of verse and php will validate it accordingly before passing it as query.

Thanks

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following pattern that seems to work.  Try this:

```
<?php

$string = '7 Genesis 16:23';

if (preg_match('/^(.*?)\s+(\d+):(\d+)$/', $string, $match)) {
    echo "You selected book {$match[1]}, chapter {$match[2]}, verse {$match[3]}!";
} else {
    echo "I couldn't understand your input.  Please use 'Book chapter:verse' format.";
}
```

The first part of the expression `(.*?)` matches the book, (1 Cor) or just (Cor), so you may need/want to do additional validation on that part or refine it, but this worked okay for me.  Hopefully gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$str = 'Gen 1:1'; // OR: $str = '1 Cor 1:1';
$array = explode( ' ', $str);
$last = end( $array);
$array = array_merge( array_slice( $array, 0, count( $array) - 1), explode( ':', $last));
var_dump( $array);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jvv3jq)

Comment: This will fail if `$str = '1 Cor 1:1'`, one of the OP's examples

Comment: @mattedgod - Missed that, fixed it now, works for both cases, thanks.

Comment: @nickb This becomes 4 parts now. It should only be 3 parts. 1Cor or 1 Cor should end up in 1 array. The parts must be book, chapter, verse. I use **drew010** code. Works for my purpose. Thanks to all who contribute. I checked all your code and I warded the question to drew010 for being the first correct answer. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should work:

```
$subject = <<verse here>>;
$pattern = '/^([0-9a-zA-Z ]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Note that the first element in `$matches` will be the full $subject. Elements 1-3 will map to your elements 0-2.

Comment: This also works. array[0] being the whole entry and array [1-3] getting the proper value of Book, Chapter, verse needed for my code.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want the following, in order:

- Some text (maybe spaces maybe not) `(.*)`
- Some spaces (at least 1) `[ ]+`
- A number (1+ digits) `([0-9]+)`
- A colon `:`
- Another number (1+ digits) `([0-9]+)`

Therefore, your regex would look like so:

```
/^(.*)[ ]*([0-9])+:([0-9]+)$/
```

After running this:

```
$m = '1 Cor 3:14';
$matches = array();
preg_match("/^(.*)[ ]*([0-9])+:([0-9]+)$/", $m, $matches);
```

`$matches` will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 Cor 3:14
    [1] => 1 Cor 
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 14
)
```