# RegEx for hashtag separated string

Tags: php, regex

I have bunch of strings like this:

```
a#aax1aay222b#bbx4bby555bbz6c#mmm1d#ara1e#abc
```

And what I need to do is to split them up based on the `hashtag` position to something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => AAX1AAY222
    [2] => B
    [3] => BBX4BBY555BBZ6
    [4] => C
    [5] => MMM1
    [6] => D
    [7] => ARA1
    [8] => E
    [9] => ABC
)
```

So, as you see the character right behind the `hashtag` is captured plus everything after the hashtag just right before the next char+hashtag.

I've the following `RegEx` which works fine **only** when I have a `numeric` value in the end of each part.

Here is the RegEx set up:

```
preg_split('/([A-Z])+#/', $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

And it works fine with something like this:

```
C#mmm1D#ara1
```

But, if I change it to this (removing the numbers):

```
C#mmmD#ara
```

Then it will be the result, which is not good:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => D
)
```

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639478/how-do-i-extract-words-starting-with-a-hash-tag-from-a-string-into-an-array) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138191/preg-match-all-after-hash-tag-before-next-hash-tag-in-a-string) one also, which are similar but none of them worked for me.

So, my question is why does it work only if it has followed by a number? and how I can solve it?

Here you can see some of them sample strings which I have:

```
a#123b#abcc#def456         // A:123, B:ABC, C:DEF456
a#abc1def2efg3b#abcdefc#8  // A:ABC1DEF2EFG3, B:ABCDEF, C:8
a#abcdef123b#5c#xyz789     // A:ABCDEF123, B:5, C:XYZ789
```

P.S. Strings are case-insensitive.

P.P.S. If you ever thinking what the hell are these strings, they are user submitted answers to a questionnaire, and I can't do anything on them like refactoring as they are already stored and just need to be proceed.

**Why Not Using explode?**

If you look at my examples you will see that I need to capture the character right before the # as well. If you think it's possible with `explode()` please post the output as well, thanks!

**Update**

Should we focus on why `/([A-Z])+#/` works only if numbers included? thanks.

Comment: @senk I need to capture the character right before the # as well.

Comment: You could `explode()` and copy the last char from the previous array item.

Comment: @Voitcus could you try it and post it as an answer? I still can't figure out how you want to capture that character with explode. Thanks.

Comment: This is very confusing, can you set different separator, can you make the string something like this: "a#aax1aay222,b#bbx4bby555bbz6,c#mmm1,d#ara1,e#abc"

Comment: @nacholibre I can do it with some tricks of course; find the #, put a `,` on `-2` position, but honestly I don't like to do that ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still want to use preg_split you can remove the `+` and it might work as expected:

```
'/([A-Z])#/i'
```

Since then you only match the hashtag and ONE alpha character before, and not all them.

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/z1kFDb

Edit: Added a case-insensitive flag `i` in the pattern.

Comment: wow, that's works pretty fine ... thanks for the explanation also!

Comment: @Mahdi You might want to use A-Za-z0-9 to get the lower/upper case working together (as in your example), and if you want to use numbers (as in your update)

Comment: @Marcus update your answer so the answer's code matches the link's code

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `preg_split()`, decide what you want to match instead:

1. A set of "words" if followed by either `<any-char>#` or `<end-of-string>`.
2. A character if immediately followed by `#`.

   ```
   $str = 'a#aax1aay222b#bbx4bby555bbz6c#mmm1d#ara1e#abc';

   preg_match_all('/\w+(?=.#|$)|\w(?=#)/', $str, $matches);
   ```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LL1bHv)

This expression uses two look-ahead assertions. The results are in `$matches[0]`.

**Update**

Another way of looking at it would be this:

```
preg_match_all('/(\w)#(\w+)(?=\w#|$)/', $str, $matches);

print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

Each entry starts with a single character, followed by a hash, followed by X characters until either the end of the string is encountered or the start of a next entry.

The output is this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => aax1aay222
    [b] => bbx4bby555bbz6
    [c] => mmm1
    [d] => ara1
    [e] => abc
)
```

Comment: that is perfect! ... thanks a lot for the help! Do you have any idea what was wrong with my regex?

Comment: `Jack`, by the way, I'm choosing `Marcus` answer as accepted because that's addressing the exact problem I was asking in the question, but thanks a lot again for your answer!

Comment: @Mahdi In most cases `preg_split()` can be turned into a `preg_match_all()` instead; in my own opinion, it makes it easier to follow the logic, even though a `preg_split()` is actually possible here.

Comment: you're right, but I meant because `Marcus` was exactly fixing my regex and it look much simpler I chose his answer as accepted. I think his solution is more efficient also. I still like the way you structure your regex, but I believe it's more fair if I go for his solution.

Comment: @Mahdi Efficiency should always be the last thing to look at, but Marcus's answer is perfectly fine :)

Comment: @Mahdi Considering a string that already starts with hashtag, Jack's answer and your own answer (with Marcus' help) give different results! In your own answer, the first item will then include the #

Comment: Same caveat goes for two consecutive hash tags.

Comment: @Mahdi I found another way that you may have overlooked; take a look at the update :)

Comment: @Jack Your update will break in both caveats I just mentioned.

Comment: @nl-x My update returns an empty array both your "caveats" because those are not supposed to occur anyway, according to the question.

Comment: @nl-x thanks for spending time on that. Fortunately those are not the case, so I don't have any string starts with # or containing ## (which is great in my mind!) ... however, I'd still say the regex approach is much more readable. Thanks again for your efforts!

Comment: @Jack I really like the way you doing in the update, I'm really learning something here ... I wish I could up vote more than one.

Comment: @Mahdi You're welcome ... tell your friends to vote for you ;-) just kidding hehe

Answer (score 1):

Use explode() rather than Regexp

```
$tmpArray = explode("#","a#aax1aay222b#bbx4bby555bbz6c#mmm1d#ara1e#abc");
$myArray = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmpArray) - 1; $i++) {
    if (substr($tmpArray[$i],0,-1)) $myArray[] = substr($tmpArray[$i],0,-1);
    if (substr($tmpArray[$i],-1)) $myArray[] = substr($tmpArray[$i],-1);
}
if (count($tmpArray) && $tmpArray[count($tmpArray) - 1]) $myArray[] = $tmpArray[count($tmpArray) - 1];
```

**edit:** I updated my answer to reflect better reading the questions

Comment: The goal is to capture the character preceding the `#` in its own array element as well; reread the question.

Comment: @nl-x well, as I mentioned above, I'm trying to avoid writing tricky codes in my projects. But thanks for the effort. :)

Comment: @nl-x +1 because of your efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode()` function that will split the string except the hash signs, like stated in the answers given before.

```
$myArray = explode("#",$string);
```

For the string 'a#aax1aay222b#bbx4bby555bbz6c#mmm1d#ara1e#abc' this returns something like

```
$myarray = array('a', 'aax1aay22b', 'bbx4bby555bbz6c' ....);
```

All you need now is to take the last character of each string in array as another item.

```
$copy = array();
foreach($myArray as $item){
  $beginning = substr($item,0,strlen($item)-1); // this takes all characters except the last one
  $ending = substr($item,-1); // this takes the last one
  $copy[] = $beginning;
  $copy[] = $ending;
} // end foreach
```

This is an example, not tested.

**EDIT**

Instead of `substr($item,0,strlen($item)-1);` you might use `substr($item,0,-1);`.

Comment: @Jack Perhaps you need to concat the last part. This also inserts empty strings when `explode` returns a single-character, maybe they should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the effort ... but you know, recently I'm trying to avoid tricks in programming, I believe there is always [at least] a proper solution for each problem. Check out the `Jack` answer as well :)

Comment: @Voitcus Thanks anyways for the effort :)