# regular expression to match querysting includes array

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match(#(?:([a-zA-Z-]+):)?(?://(?:([a-zA-Z0-9_!$&\'()*+,;=._~%-]+)(?::([a-zA-Z0-9_!$&\'()*+,;=._~%-]*))?@)?([a-zA-Z0-9-._]+)(?::([0-9]*))?)?([a-zA-Z0-9_!$&\'()*@+,:;=._~/%-]*)(?:\\?([0-9a-zA-Z!$&\'()*@+,:;=._~%-]*))?(?:\\#(.*))?#, $uri, $m));
```

the regex above is used to match urls and the result is supposed to be 
m[1] = scheme  m[2] = user  m[3] = pass  m[4] = host  m[5] = port  m[6] = path  m[7] = queryString  m[8] = fragment

it works well except when the queryString includes array, 
for example: 
?ar[k1]=v1&ar[k2]=v2

My questions are:
1.What is the meaning of the sharp # in the regex
2.how can I modify the regex to make it matches the queryString include array

Comment: With all due respect but you are doing this the wrong way :) There are far better ways to parse these kind of strings and they do not require regexes. Try `parse_str` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for example.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use a regex for this. However, if you are clueless as to how they work, you shouldn't try to adapt it. In paticular if it's condensed and uncommented like this one. -- Else[Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.The sharp (# 2nd) in the regex meaning a part of [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)

scheme://username:password@domain:port/path?query_string`#`fragment_id

2.[Parse a URL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and return its components

Answer (score 3):

You are better of using [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url), captures the querystring also, which you can then use with [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/parse_str) to get an array of key -> value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Use `parse_str` instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

This does exactly what you required and is built-in, and most importantly, sans regex (look at that monster) :s.

To directly answer your question by the way, `#` is just a delimiter of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression seems to be quite strictly adapting the syntax of URIs as per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) which actually doesn’t allow plain `[` or `]` inside the [query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3):

> ```
>   query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
>   pchar       = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
>   unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
>   pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
>   sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>               / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

Now if you want to allow these characters too, use this for the query part in your existing regular expression:

```
… (?:\\?([0-9a-zA-Z!$&\'()*@+,:;=._~%[\]-]*))? …
```