# regex for <!--{tag}--> or <!--{tag(string|integer|etc)}-->?

Tags: php, regex

I have these:

```
<!--{tag}-->
```

and

```
<!--{tag(integer)}-->
```

and

```
<!--{tag('argument1')}-->
```

and

```
<!--{tag('argument1', 'argument2',... 'argumentn')}-->
```

I am looking for single pattern, that can handle all of them, I have tried this for the first one, but I have no idea with the second pattern, to the fourth:

```
<!--\{tag\}-->
```

ps: 
*argument can be an integer (with no quote) or a string with single quote (or double quote).
*The pattern can extract the information in argument

Thanks

Comment: You could also try it yourself first. * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: Yep thanks, but I'm looking solution for complex pattern here.

Comment: Requests for [just code](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help5) are usually off-topic. Primary site intent is coding approaches, not readymade solutions.

Comment: @mario: But my point is for regex pattern, not for just code. If you are questioned about the preg_match php it's in the context of "no objection". I do not force someone should create it

Comment: It's arguably one of the less boring regex questions here, and I do not want to prohibit it getting answered. Yet it didn't attract expert answers so far, and is unlikely because you didn't show prior research or proof with your existing regex code. -- To me it's super trivial, so I wonder what you're stumbling over. And second if you're already aware that a PCRE regex won't extract separated arguments, much less with integer|string|etc type qualifiers. Also is the `'tag'` a fixed string, etc?

Comment: @mario: Oh I don't think so, I was google it first before create this post, and searching in stackoverflow. If you boring, it's your problem. Stackoverflow is for answering people like me. You are arogant because you feel that you are senior and superior here. I did put a 'tag' because it is static. I have own scenario for my code. Thanks

Comment: No need to get grumpy. This was a genuine inquiry for once. You didn't mention either (googling / searching), so it's legitimate to ask for. You can avoid that by posting sample code, especially and even if it's wrong or imperfect. This way you also avoid getting redundant suggestions of what you possibly tried already.

Comment: @mario: I am not grumpy here. It seems that is you, by downvoting me. lol :P reputation in stackoverflow is not important for me FYI :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but this is what I came up with:

```
<!--\{tag(?:\(((?:\d+)|(?:'\w+')|(?:(?:['"]?\w+['"]?,\s*){1,}['"]?[\w\d]+['"]?))\))?\}-->
```

You can [see from the regexer](http://regexr.com?31hh4) that it is matching every one of your test cases.

However, it will also match the following test cases, which I am leaving up to the OP to determine how to correct.

```
<!--{tag(argument1, 2)}--> (missing quotes around string arguments)
<!--{tag("argument1', 2)}--> (unmatched single and double quotes)
<!--{tag(2, "arg)}--> (missing unmatched quotes)
```

Comment: Ok. It's not perfect but it is what I'm looking for. I have to refine it. Thanks :)

Comment: Looks more than good enough for assertion and extraction. I'd do an spacey `/x` regex for such cases already, and the `?(DEFINE)` with named patterns for the super exact/complex case. A second regex to split up the params is easier anyway.

Comment: @mario: Actually, this is not perfect answer, I have to combine and refine this pattern with my own scenario and pattern out there in google. You just arrogant bro, you feel that you are senior and superior here. Just it

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--\{tag(\([0-9]+|'[a-zA-Z0-9]+'\))?\}-->
```

There may be some escaping issues, I don't really have an enviroment to test right now, but the pattern should work.

You basically look for tag, which can optionally have one of the two extra suffixes in brackets.

Comment: please wait, I'll check that one. Thanks

Comment: Your pattern can't pass : <!--{tag(6)}--> or <!--{tag('string')}-->

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `<!--\{tag.*?\}-->`
for extract argument use `(?<=<!--\{tag).*?(?=\}-->)`

Comment: But, it can't extract the information inside the (). Ok, I'm sorry, I should edit the post for more clearly