# Differences between (.*) and (.*?)

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does lazy and greedy means in regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-does-lazy-and-greedy-means-in-regexp)

I know that in Regex the question mark after *, + or ? means ungreedy but if I want to match any character, what is the difference between using (.*) or (.*?) ?

Thanks.

EDIT:
In my case I want to check a URL. What are the differences between

```
http://site\.net/(.*?)\.html
```

and

```
http://site\.net/(.*)\.html
```

?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-does-lazy-and-greedy-means-in-regexp

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools that can analyze and explain given patterns, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: @Matteo: Added explanation for your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that you got this url:

```
http://example.net/some/wierd/path.html?returnTo=somedoc.html
```

Greedy would match entire line:

```
http://example.net/some/wierd/path.html?returnTo=somedoc.html
```

while non greedy returns:

```
http://example.net/some/wierd/path.html
```

Answer (score 21):

`.*` is greedy, meaning that it will ignore the next delimiter of your regex until it itself is not fulfilled, unless the regex following `.*` is against the end of the target string.

`.*?` is ungreedy, meaning that it will proceed to the next delimiter of your regex, *if* the next is fulfilled.  It will continue onto the next delimiter even if itself is still applicable.

Example:

`/(.*) dog/` will match "I think your dog bit my dog" and group 1 will be "I think your dog bit my".

`/(.*?) dog/` will match "I think your dog bit my dog" and group 1 will be "I think your".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He already says he knows that a `?` makes the regular expression ungreedy

Comment: Yes, I wanted something like an example..

Answer (score 6):

If there's nothing following the `(.*)` in the regular expression then there is absolutely no difference. However, if there *is* anything following, then there is a difference:

```
"I went to the shops and then I went home"

/(.*) went/  => "[I went to the shops and then I] went"
/(.*?) went/ => "[I] went"
```

Answer (score 2):

As you already know hat ungreedy behaviour is, I won't explain that again.

It depends on what comes **after** the `(.*?)` - That's what's ungreedy behaviour for.

Interestingely enough, this means that a regex in the form `/(.*?)/` doesn't make much sense - because how can you be lazy, if you match everyting anyway?

If you try to create this regex in e.g. [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u0fj), it won't even compile, because it's nonsense.

Only if you put something behind the group, your regex will make any kind of sense. I'm not sure if all rege engines do the same as Regexr here and deny to accept that regex.

So, if you want to match anything until a certain character, you'd have to put that specific character **after** your ungreedy-anything-group. This way, everything before that particular character is matched.

To bring it to a conclusion; it doesn't make any difference, **IF** there isn't something AFTER the group.