# re parsing data from text file

Tags: php, html, pcre

ok i know its been awhile and i am not sure if i should start a new thread

but i have figured out how to remove to remove the two middle parts, all the parentheses and srgba, also the lines with zero alpha, but somehow it leaves an open space in the text file. if there is any improvements that anybody can see.

```
$fh = fopen("pcmanD.txt", "r");
$fg = fopen("pcmanJ.txt", "wt");
$new_array = ""; $parts = "";
while (!feof($fh)) {
    $line = fgets($fh);
    $lines[] = $line;
    $newword = "";
    $match1 ="/:\s?\s?\(\s?\s?\d+,\s?\s?\d+,\s?\s?\d+,\s?\s?\d+\)\s?\s?#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,8}\s?\s?srgba/";
    $match2 ="/^\s\s?/";
    $match3 = "/\s\(/";
    $match4 = "/\)/";
    $match5 = "/[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},0[^\.]/";

    $parts1 = preg_replace($match1,"", $line );
    $parts2 = preg_replace($match2,"", $parts1 );
    $parts3 = preg_replace($match3,",", $parts2 );
    $parts4 = preg_replace($match4,"", $parts3 );
    $parts5 = preg_replace($match5,"",$parts4);


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($parts5);
    echo "</pre>";

    fwrite($fg, $parts5);
} 

fclose($fg);
fclose($fh);
```

but new problem arises with this code where i get double or triple on the floating points after the match.

```
$thisisit[] = "";
$thisisit2[] = "";
$countThis = 0;
$fh = fopen("sometext.txt", "r");
$new_array = ""; $parts = "";
while (!feof($fh)) {
    $line = fgets($fh);
    $line2 = $line;
    $newword = "";
    $match1 ="/^\s*?[\d]+,[\d]+/";
    $parts1 = preg_match($match1, $line, $regs);
    foreach($regs as $key => $lame) {
        $thisisit[] = $lame;
    }
    $match2 ="/(?:(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},))(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3},[01][\.]?[\d]*)/";
    $parts2 = preg_match($match2, $line2, $regs2);
    foreach($regs2 as $key2 => $lame2) {
        $thisisit2[] =$lame2;
    }
    $countLame = count($thisisit);
} 

echo "</script>";
$newCounter = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < (500); $i++) {
    echo  $thisisit[$i] . "<br />";
    echo $thisisit2[$newCounter] . "<br />" ;
    $newCounter = $newCounter +4;
}
fclose($fh);
```

here is some text in the text file i am working on

```
42,23,162,166,48,0.156863
 43,23,162,166,47,0.156863
 44,23,167,170,67,0.219608
 45,23,162,166,47,0.156863
 46,23,167,170,67,0.219608
 47,23,162,166,37,0.117647
 48,23,162,167,32,0.0941176
                                      86,23,163,167,40,0.12549
 87,23,160,164,47,0.164706
 88,23,188,190,122,0.352941
 86,24,233,234,197,0.486275
 87,24,251,250,250,1
 88,24,251,250,250,1
 89,24,251,250,250,1
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your code? It sounded like this is a continuation of another post. If so you should link to it.

Comment: kinda is but it is same stuff more or less  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715889/parse-a-text-file-containing-image-data