# Replacing characters that occurs after 2nd and 3rd dash

Tags: php, string

I have a string in following patterns.

```
A-B-C-D
A-AB-C-DP
AQ-B-MN-QD
```

and so on. The pattern follows same rule that each string has 4 group of letter(s) separated by a dash. But string might have a group with any combination of one or two letters as above.

Now what i want to do is replace the letter(s) that comes after 2nd and 3rd dash.

if the letters in group have been consistent, it would have easier for me to  use `strpos` and `substr` functions to do that. But here the letters are not consistent in a group. How to do this in this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Variable-length strings with recurring patterns are simpler to work on with regular expressions. * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: Do you need to validate, as well as replace? Or are you confident (confident === you already checked) that the string is valid?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, I dont need to validate, I just need to replace

Comment: @LoVeSmItH: JvdBerg's answer is the one for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would explode the string into a array, process it and implode back to a string:

```
$a = explode('-', $string);
// do stuf on element 2 and 3
$string = implode('-', $a);
```

Answer (score 2):

$string = a-b-c-d;

list($a,$b,$c,$d) = explode("-",$string);

You can then concatenate from there.

Answer (score 1):

Regex's way. Try replace `$2`, `$3` with your value

```
# replace $2, $3 with the value that you want
echo preg_replace('#([^-]+)\-([^-]+)\-([^-]+)\-([A-Z]+)#', '$1-$2-$3-$4', 'AQ-B-MN-QD');
```