# find several words by regex criteria php

Tags: php

I want to replace some strings by other one.
I use below codes:

```
$mc = 'Hello I have these bages: [A-561],[A-123],[A-1],[A-5234]';
$medal = '<img src="1" />';
$bages = preg_replace('/^\[A-[0-9]+\]/i',$medal,$mc);
echo $bages
```

it prints out this:

```
Hello I have these bages: [A-561],[A-123],[A-1],[A-5234]
```

and if i change $mc to

```
$mc = "[A-561],[A-123],[A-1],[A-5234]";
```

then prints out:

```
<img src="1" />,[A-123],[A-1],[A-5234]
```

I have no idea why it happens like this. i want to change all of them to my replace string.

Comment: You have an `^` in your regex. Do you know what it means?
 * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^` in your regex makes the regex only match on the start of a string.

Remove that `^` from the regex:

```
$bages = preg_replace('/\[A-[0-9]+\]/i',$medal,$mc);
```