# Simple phone number regex for php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've been looking for a simple phone number regex that will match just this format:
(XXX) XXX-XXXX  <---with the parentheses and the space after them required

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this wont work (This was one that I tried making myself and have been tinkering with for hours):

```
^[\(0-9\){3} [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```

I've looked everywhere online for a regex with that particular format matching to no avail.
Please help?

Comment: well, that's actually not what I have. It's really /^\([0-9]\){3} [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/

Comment: OK, I guess it's taking out the backslashes that I had in it for some reason

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: Just so you know, i haven't personally written a phone number like `(###) ###-####` in maybe 10 years.  Now that many phone services require or at least support entering the area code as part of the number, it seems a bit of a relic.  `###-###-####` makes more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following regex works

```
^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$

^ = start of line
\( = matches parenthesis open
\d = digit (0-9)
\) = matches parenthesis close
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a working one

```
/^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}\s$/
```

the problems with your's:

to match digits just use `\d` or `[0-9]` (square brackets are needed, you've forgot them in first occurence)
to match parenthesis use `\(` and `\)`. They have to be escaped, otherwise they will be interpreted as match and your regex won't compile

Answer (score 1):

The problems you are having are:

1. You need to escape special characters (like parentheses) with a backslash, like this: `\(`
2. You have an unclosed square bracket at the beginning.

Otherwise, you're good!

Answer (score 0):

`[]` define character classes. e.g. "at this one single character spot, any of the following can match". Your brackets are misaligned:

```
^[\(0-9\){3} [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
 ^---no matching closer
```

e.g.

```
^[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```

would be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\(\d{3}+\)+ \d{3}+\-\d{4}+)/ (000) 000-0000

/(\d{3}+\-\d{3}+\-\d{4}+)/ 000-000-0000
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED `^\(?\d{3}\)?\s?\-?\d{3}\s?\-?\d{4}$`

in Php works for the following

(999) 999 9999

(999) 999-9999

(999) 999-9999

999 999 9999

999 999-9999

999-999-9999

Comment: What is the purpose of `?` after `\d{4}`. This regex is matching `(1234567890` or `123) -456 -7890`.