# Using preg_match to validate phone number format

Tags: php, regex

I am having issues making a function that validates that a phone number is in this exact format(xxx)xxx-xxxx.

My attempt was to use preg_match to confirm that the number is in the given format, but I'm having issues with the pattern.

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]){3}[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/", $field)
```

I think my issue is that I don't know how to handle parenthesis in preg_match.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple phone number regex for php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13111295)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape parenthesis : `\(` and `\)`

try this:

```
$n = "(123)456-3890";
$p = "/\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}/";

preg_match($p,$n,$m);

var_dump($m);
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work using your format.  I have a question though.  I've seem examples with "^" at the start of the pattern and "$" at the end. What are those for?

Comment: Beginning and end respectively. You would use iff you're validating a single input and the phone number should be the only thing allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can have all this number validation by this code,

```
<?php
$array = array(
'0 000 (000) 000-0000',
'000 (000) 000-0000',
'0-000-000-000-0000',
'000 (000) 000-0000',
'000-000-000-0000',
'000-00-0-000-0000',
'0000-00-0-000-0000',
'+000-000-000-0000',
'0 (000) 000-0000',
'+0-000-000-0000',
'0-000-000-0000',
'000-000-0000',
'(000) 000-0000',
'000-0000',
'+9981824139',
9981824139,
919981824139,
'+919981824139',
'qwqwqwqwqwqwqw'
);

foreach($array AS $no){    
            var_dump( ( preg_match( '/\d?(\s?|-?|\+?|\.?)((\(\d{1,4}\))|(\d{1,3})|\s?)(\s?|-?|\.?)((\(\d{1,3}\))|(\d{1,3})|\s?)(\s?|-?|\.?)((\(\d{1,3}\))|(\d{1,3})|\s?)(\s?|-?|\.?)\d{3}(-|\.|\s)\d{4}/', $no )
            ||
            preg_match('/([0-9]{8,13})/', str_replace(' ', '', $no))
            ||
            ( preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', $no) && strlen($no) >= 8 && strlen($no) <= 13 ) )
          );
    }

//var_dump (preg_match('/([0-9]{8,12})/', '99818241') );
//var_dump( strlen(9981) );

//var_dump (preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', '+12345678') );
//var_dump (preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', '12345678') );
```

This will Validate your all type of phone number and output would be

> ```
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(true)
> bool(false)
> ```