# How to match a regular expression that contains an arbitrary string, and get only that arbitrary string into a variable using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to write a very simple markup language in PHP that contains tags like [x=123], and I need to be able to match that tag and extract only the value of x.

I'm assuming the answer involves regex but maybe I'm wrong.

So if we had a string:

```
$str = "F9F[x=]]^$^$[x=123]#3j3E]]#J";
```

And a regular expression to match:

```
/^\[x=.+\]$/
```

How would we get only the ".+" portion of the matching string into a variable?

Comment: It's called capture groups. Your regex incorrectly looks for `^` start and `$` end, and the `.+` is too greedy.
 * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **preg_match** to search a string for a regular expression.

Check out the documentation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for more information on how to use it (as well as some examples). You might also want to take a look at **preg_grep**.

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work for you:

```
$str = "F9F[x=]]^$^$[x=123]#3j3E]]#J";
if (preg_match('~\[x=(?<valX>\d+)\]~', $str, $match))
   echo $match['valX'] . "\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
123
```