# Customize regular expression of php

Tags: php, regex

i have a string which is something like

```
<?php
$string = Monday & SUNDAY 11:30 PM et/pt;
//or
$string = Monday 11:30 PM et/pt;
?>
```

i want to fetch '11:30 PM' in both the cases for which i guess i cant use explode so what will be the regular expression for this ,,,also please tell me something pretty nice to learn regular expressions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's simple. Did you try anything yet? (Your title says "customize").
 * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: try this website : http://regex.inginf.units.it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to the commenters below for several fixes to the original approach, but there were still some unresolved issues.

If you want a fixed 2 hour format: `(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d [AP]M`

Comment: I guess, this should be `[0-2][0-9]`

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle this is turning out to be less my answer and more everyone else's. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to validly match a [twelve-our-clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) i'd use a regex like below. A twelve-hour-clock goes from 01:00 to 12:59:

```
$regex = "#\b(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [AP]M\b#i";
```

Comment: The second non-capturing subpattern is not useful because you do not have to locate a set of alternatives. You can also add words boundary to improve the performance of the regexp: `#\b(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [AP]M\b#i`

Answer (score 0):

Malik, to retrieve time/date you might use premade library regexes, search this query: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=digit&c=5&m=-1&ps=20

Basically your time fields are similar, (having the same delimiter *':'* ), i'd recommend simple regex: `\d{1,2}:\d{2} [PA]M` to match in the input string. If you want make it case-insensitive use *i*, [pattern modifier](http://extract-web-data.com/regex-in-php/#modifiers).
For the basics of regex welcome to read [here](http://extract-web-data.com/regex-expressions/).

I give you this match function for PHP (*i* after second slash (/) makes pattern case-insensitive: `am, AM, Am, aM` will be equal):

```
  preg_match('/\d{1,2}:\d{2} [PA]M/i', $string, $time);
  print ($time);
```

If there might not be a space after digits (ex. 11:30am) or more then one space char., then the regex should look like this:
 `/\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s*[PA]M/i`

Answer (score -1):

this code will give you **11:30 PM**

```
preg_match('$([0-9:]{3,5}) ([AP])M$','Monday & SUNDAY 11:30 PM et/pt',$m);
echo $m['1']." ".$m['2']."M";
```

Comment: Slight problem with a `$` at the beginning. Perhaps you meant `^`

Comment: no i meant $. what is the problem? you can use any non-alphanumeric character for delimiter.

Comment: your regex matches 99:99 PM, 9:999 AM, 9:9 AM and 000:0 PM. seems wrong.

Comment: @MC_delta_T Yeah sorry, I mistook the first and last `$` for anchor tokens. @kai, also matches `::: PM`

Comment: i didnt say/thought any validation issue. this is the simplest solution for this problem. if we think on it, can add a lot of code. i think no need too much complexity.