# How to include dashes in this regular expression

Tags: php, regex

This snippet of code is taken from codeigniter and i'm trying to copy it into a new function that allows numeric characters and dashes. What do i need to add to this regex to allow dashes and parenthesis as well?

```
preg_match( '/^[\-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/', $str);
```

Comment: Add them to the character class? * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match( '/^\+?[-0-9]*\.?[-0-9]+$/', $str);
```

update:

```
preg_match( '/^\+?[-0-9()]*\.?[-0-9()]+$/', $str);
```

Comment: I updated the question to allow parenthesis as well. Can you update your answer?

Comment: Updated. Not sure at which place you are required in parenthesis though, some examples of `$str` would rock.

Comment: I'm trying to allow users to enter a phone number in multiple formats including `555-555-5555` or `(555) 555-555`.

Comment: Better to use this one then `preg_match('/^\+?[-0-9() ]+[0-9]{1}$/', trim($str))`.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression means this:
Begin the line with a - or + MAYBE
Then 0-9 zero or more times
Then a . MAYBE
Then end with AT LEAST ONE of the following numbers: 0-9

You need to specify what you want the RegEx to do, then someone can write a correct RegEx.

*EDIT*
Here you go:

```
<?php

// 555-555-5555 or (555) 555-5555 or (555)555-5555
$str = '555-555-5555';
if (preg_match( '/^((\([0-9]{3}\)) ?|[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/', $str) == 1){
    echo 'Yes!';
}else{
    echo 'No!';
}
?>
```

Comment: The code posted in the question was taken straight out of the codeigniter function "Numeric" in the form_validation class. I just wanted to add dashes and parenthesis to it so that they are allowed as well.

Comment: @Catfish, The answer you marked correct allows `+- -)(0` Does that look like anyone's phone number?

Comment: It's ok for my application because i strip anything but numbers to insert it into the database. It's just so people can enter a variety of formats.

Comment: I'm guessing it allows `+` or `-` because the codeigniter `numeric` format must allow for numbers like `-2`, `+2`, etc.