# RegEx To Validate 4 and 5 Digit Numbers?

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex :

```
if(preg_match("@^\d{4}$@", basename($entry, ".php"))) {
--do something here--
}
```

that condition works only for 4 digits number. but I need to validate 4 digits and also 5 digits. how to make it work to validate 5 digits number too? thanks!

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the braces can take a low and high end of a range so `{4,5}` should work.

Comment: +1 for the regular expression explanation. I encourage you to also provide a code sample.

Comment: Here's something you can run on the command line: `php -r '$pattern = "/^\d{4,5}/"; preg_match($pattern, "12345678", $a); print_r($a);'`

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Regular Expressions, consider simpler functions like [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) and [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen).

```
$filename = basename($entry, ".php");
$length = strlen($filename);

if (($length >= 4 && $length <= 5) && ctype_digit($filename)) {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(preg_match("@^\d{4,5}$@", basename($entry, ".php"))) {
--do something here--
}
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
 if(preg_match("@^\d{4}$@", basename($entry, ".php"))) {
```

use

```
if(preg_match("@^\d{4,5}$@", basename($entry, ".php"))) {
```