# Match substrings like $Q1o1

Tags: php, regex

I need to pull out of a this string of characters after $

```
($Q1==1)and($Q4o=="55")and($Q1o1=="")
```

I mean these `$Q1`, `$Q4o`, `$Q1o1`

As I understand, the regular expression should start searching from `$` and end on any character except `A-Za-z0-9_`.  Can you help me write the regex?

Comment: Please elaborate on your use case. Are you trying to parse PHP code, or a subset thereof? (Then the tokenizer might be simpler.)
 * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Have you tried to come up with one on your own yet?  Here's a hint: in regex, `$` means "end of string", so you'll need to escape it: `\$`.

Comment: What is the regular format you're looking to match? Is it always `$Q` followed by something random, or are the more specific rules in place?

Comment: no, $Q1 is not a variable, simple string  
i know a theory of regex, but always fails in real :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work, at least in Ruby:

```
/\$\w*/
```

Be careful with the $, as $ is a reserved symbol in regular expressions that means "end of the string", so you need to escape it.

Comment: Oh, damn, thanks, @RocketHazmat. I should check these things before writing them.

Comment: I figured you just typed it too quickly or something :-P

Answer (score 0):

`/\$([[:alnum:]]+)[[^:alnum:]]/`

You'll want to pull out the first bracketed expression.

EDIT: I prefer the other suggestion, using \w*