# check the value entered by the user with regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex, validation

in my program php, I want the user doesn't enter any caracters except the alphabets
like that : "dgdh", "sgfdgdfg" but he doesn't enter the numbers or anything else like "7657" or "gfd(-" or "fd54"
I tested this function but it doesn't cover all cases :

```
preg_match("#[^0-9]#",$_POST['chaine'])
```

how can I achieve that, thank you in advance

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest can be

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', $_POST['chaine'])
```

the `i` modifier is for case-insensitive.  The `+` is so that at least one alphabet is entered.  You can change it to `*` if you want to allow empty string.  The anchor `^` and `$` enforce that the whole string is nothing but the alphabets.  (they represent the beginning of the string and the end of the string, respectively).

---

**If you want to allow whitespace**, you can use:

Whitespace only at the beginning or end of string:

```
preg_match('/^\s*[a-z]+\s*$/i', $_POST['chaine'])
```

Any where:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z][\sa-z]*$/i', $_POST['chaine'])    // at least one alphabet
```

Only the space character is allowed but not other whitespace:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z][ a-z]*$/i', $_POST['chaine'])
```

Comment: thank you 動靜能量, this is another good idea, I didn't think about the whitespace

Answer (score 0):

**Only** match letters *(no whitespace)*:

```
preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z]+$#",$_POST['chaine'])
```

Explanation:

```
^         # matches the start of the line
[a-zA-Z]  # matches any letter (upper or lowercase)
+         # means the previous pattern must match at least once
$         # matches the end of the line
```

With whitespace:

```
preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z ]+$#",$_POST['chaine'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things. Firstly, you match non-digit characters. That is obviously not the same as letter characters. So you could simply use `[a-zA-Z]` or `[a-z]` and the case-insensitive modifier instead.

Secondly you only try to find one of those characters. You don't assert that the whole string is composed of these. So use this instead:

```
preg_match("#^[a-z]*$#i",$_POST['chaine'])
```