# Regular expression hash match

Tags: php, regex

The regex below takes the number (company id) out from the URL below, but I'm trying to find out how it works. What does hash to and pluses do?

```
preg_match('#/company/([0-9]+)/(.+)#',http://test.net.au/company/198/test,$m);
```

Comment: the `#` here is regexp boundaries, the `+` is the any number of character before `+` (>=1)

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial. And the PHP manual explains quite a bit too: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Answer (score 1):

Hash here is a regular expression delimiter. You can use almost anything as a delimiter, like `~`, `!`, etc.

`+` is a quantifier that means repetition from 1 to infinity.

```
[0-9]+ --- 1 or more numbers in a row
.+     --- any character one or more times in a row
```

Answer (score 1):

The first and last characters in the regex are delimiters. They are there just to say here is where the regex starts and here is where it stops:

Usually `/` is used:

```
Example: "/foo/";
         "#bar#";
```

In your example you are trying to match `"/company/"` so the delimiter can't be a `/` so `#` is used instead.

The plus `+` means match 1 or more of the previous entry. Meaning in your case it will match one or more digits (From 0 to 9)

Answer (score 1):

The hashes are just used as the regex pattern's bounding delimiters.  Commonly developers use `/`, `~`, or `#` for this.  In this case `#` was used to prevent the need to escape the `/`'s in the regex pattern.

The `+` indicates that there must be one or more of the preceding element, which in the first case is actually a character class specifying all digits. In the second case it just means there need to be one or more of any character (`.` is wildcard).