# Using regular expressions to find occurence of a string

Tags: php, regex, string, match

I'm trying to use a regular expression to search for a pattern where the string will always be 5 lowercase letters, 2 numbers, and then a lower case `p`.

Example:

```
ingja44p
```

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: So what exactly is it that you want? Do you want to make sure a string has this pattern? Do you want to find this pattern inside a larger string? Do you want to extract something (like the 2 digits) from the string? [Here is a great tutorial] to get you up to speed on regular expressions. And [this family of functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) is what you use in PHP.

Comment: Lots of ppl downvoting lately... :(

Comment: @Prof83 the downvoting is not a problem, since the question shows no own effort and is not at all clear. The problem is people downvoting without leaving comments.

Comment: I guess that's what i mean... only see you comment

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us what you tried that doesn't work.  Best of all, show us the code that you're using the regex in.

Comment: @Prof83 and I didn't even downvote ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/[a-z]{5}[0-9]{2}p/');
```

The / start and end the pattern: "/PATTERN/"

The [a-z]{5} means any lowercase letters a-z for length of 5

The [0-9]{2} means any 2 digits

p means,  a "p" :)

Comment: Thanks Prof83, great help, explanation is perfect - Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There are many [utilities on the internet](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/) that can help you author and test your own regular expressions. For this case, though, you might try something like this:

```
$subject = "String to test";
$pattern = "#[a-z]{5}\d{2}p#";

if (preg_match($pattern, $subject)) {
   echo "A match was found.";
}
```

Comment: To help him/her understand, \d means DECIMAL equivalent to [0-9] :)

Comment: Exactly. What @Prof83 said :^)