# Regex- downloading certain files that match the regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a database that has a list of servers that I am downloading data from. I want to add a column that has a regex pattern so that my program can only download files that match this pattern.

Having never learnt regex before, I am in need of a little help.

I currently want the regex to match any files that have a extension of `.edi`.
How would I go about this?

How about matching the filename exact (as some customers may want)? For instances, the file is always going to be called `salesorder.txt`.

What if the customer doesn't want to match on any file, and wants us to pull all files? Is there a regex that will grab everything.. or is a blank regex the same as that?

Thanks!

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .edi extension files: `.*\.edi$`

For fixed filename "salesroder.txt" `^salesorder\.txt$`

Comment: Thanks. I have the exact above regex in a string, but I am getting the following error: [PHP Warning] preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found. I am using the following code: if ( ! preg_match($job["file_filter"], $tmp["file"]) ) continue;

Comment: Putting slashes at the start at end appears to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Did you use "//" to wrap regex? Like this: $pattern = '/^def/'; ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php. Okay, I saw you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

To match anything

> .*

the dot means "whichever character" and the star means "any amount of them"
And @Billy chan answered the rest