# Perl Compatible Regular Expressions info

Tags: php, regex, editor

I recently studying 'Regular Expressions' and came across 2 forms of it. POSIX-Regex and PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)

Many editors support searching via 'Regular Expressions', do they consider both of the above forms? Is it that one if more used than other? Also are there any good guides to learn PCRE Expressions, currently I am reading: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are even many more types of regular expressions. You might want to call them dialects.

What type of regex is applied by editors is often not clearly shown. You will have to rely on the documentation or make a few tests yourself to find out. There are tools where you can switch between different types.

As far as I know PCRE are the most commom type supported. Not because they are better, in fact POSIX is more logical, but simply because their processing is more efficient.

Comment: Aren't there extra contstructs in PCRE that make it a bit more powerful as well?  (e.g. look-arounds)