# Regex replacing folder in path

Tags: php, regex, replace

Let's assume this paths:

```
"...../site/configurationEN/database"
"....../site/configurationDE/database"
"....../site/configurationFR/database"
...
"....../site/configurationXX/database"
```

where XX can have many values for many countries.

How can i remove the XX characters from my path using regex replace and PHP?
I need an expresion that would change any of the strings above in :

```
"....../site/configuration/database"
```

Thank you!

Comment: take a look at the `preg_replace()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that :

```
<?php
$path = "site/configurationDE/database";
$newPath = preg_replace('#^(.*site/configuration)[A-Z]{2}#', '$1', $path);
?>
```

Comment: thanks! I made a small edit - added "....../" because i'm not sure what the path will be - i am sure online that it will exist a folder /configurationXX/

Comment: Sure, i already did it. Can you update the answer so it will fit the changed strings?