# Regex to find the string that starts with capital letter and is without "<" sign

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse following code:

```
<td class='postac'>Actelsar </td>
<td class='postac'>tabl. 80 mg 28 tabl.</td>
```

The input should be the text (without "<" sign) between "`<td class='postac'> </td>`" tags and that starts with capital letter.

Regex: `/<td class=\'postac\'>^[A-Z]+([^<]*)$<\/td>/s`

The code above doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) instead

Comment: @Havelock: why to prefer XPath over regular expressions *in this particular case*?

Comment: `^` means start of subject, and `$` end of subject. Which won't ever work if there is some text in front and something behind it. -- See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: Trying to parse HTML with regular expression is bad. See Havelocks comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454 It's not about "a particular case", it's about the whole idea to even try it.

Comment: @KingCrunch: it's not a HTML parsing, it's a check if an arbitrary string matches arbitrary format. It's the nothing different to checking the nickname fits the some pattern using regex

Comment: @zerkms because I think the OP is crawling pages and parsing them

Comment: @zerkms Well, may be, but must say, that I'm not completely convinced. The OP doesn't tell, whats the goal and because it is obvious a HTML table I have to assume, that he tries to parse HTML.

Comment: @KingCrunch: well, seems like it's subjective. For me it looks like a matching to the format, nothing more.

Comment: "The OP doesn't tell, whats the goal and because it is obvious a HTML table I have to assume, that he tries to parse HTML" --- he said "I'm trying to parse following code:" --- which is definitely not a valid HTML, but a piece of it, which "by chance" looks like an HTML :-)

Comment: @zerkms The OP might be matching against results of unit tests, then maybe yes, but still would take the other approach if I wouldn't feel comfortable with RegExps

Comment: You say that it's not HTML parsing, but it *is* HTML parsing.

Comment: @Havelock Thanks for the link. I'll look at this after learning the regex's basics;)

Comment: @Andy Lester: how this task differs from this: please help me match the string that starts with capital letter and doesn't contain `<` from the string `Foo Bar <baz@domain.tld>`? Is there any conceptual difference? (keep in mind I took the exact task definition, but another string)

Comment: Using regular expressions on non-regular languages (e.g. HTML, XML, any programming language) is OK for a one-time command line hack.  For for anything expected to work repeatedly, use the proper parser.

Comment: @kevin cline: is it "allowed" to parse a name from the string using regex `Foo Bar <baz@domain.tld>`? And from the string `Foo Bar </baz@domain.tld>`? And from the string `Foo Bar </baz>`? And from the string `<baz>Foo Bar </baz>`? And from the string `[baz]Foo Bar [/baz]`? On which step it becomes a big no-no-no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code above doesn't work

It doesn't because for some reason you've put a `$` and `^` signs in the middle of regex (which means the end and the beginning of the string/line correspondingly)

This should do what you want:

```
/<td class=\'postac\'>([A-Z][^<]*)<\/td>/s
```

Comment: Good old questions about micro-optimization: Wouldn't `[A-Z]` be more efficient, instead `[A-Z]+`? The parser can stop after the capital letter to look for capital letters and just go on with the others. Well, while writing I realize, that the worst case is a single wrong test... Nothing said :)

Answer (score 2):

**Use HTML parser to parse HTML not Regular Expression**. It can be easily done by DOMDocument and DOMXPath.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//td[@class="postac"]');
$result = array();
for($i=0;$i<$nodes->length; $i++){
    $text = $nodes->item($i)->textContent;
    if(isset($text[0])&&ctype_upper($text[0])) $result[]= $text;
}
```

See the [**code in action**](http://3v4l.org/qGSNZ).

Comment: That's great until he gets `<td class="postac">` or `<td class= 'postac'>` or `<td class='postac' >` or `<td class='postac' id='foo'>` or `<td class='postac'>` followed by a line feed before the name starts, or....

Comment: Yes I know that. I was actually changing my code. See update. Its changed.

Comment: Your code is 5 times longer than the one with regex and it doesn't even check for the requirement from the question (about capital letter)

Comment: @zerkms But it handles everything very well and it takes short time to write it.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: what it handles actually? "and that starts with capital letter." - m? The fanatical following some "dogmas" is not good in programming.

Comment: `$text{0}` - curly braces are not recommended to use nowadays. What if there is an empty string? This code will throw a notice?

Comment: @zerkms wasting hours to find a regex when you dont know one is not productive either.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: wasting time to write 8 lines of code that are notice-prone instead of a single line isn't more productive

Comment: @kevin cline: what is the criteria for the answer to be called "right"?

Answer (score 0):

`/<td class=\'postac\'>([A-Z]+.*)<\/td>/` will match `Actelsar`, but not tabl. 80 mg tabl.

Comment: Might be worth noting:  It will also match `Actelsar </td><td class='postac'>tabl. 80 mg 28 tabl.` from `<td class='postac'>Actelsar </td><td class='postac'>tabl. 80 mg 28 tabl.</td>`

Comment: Righto, was testing on Rubular with multiple lines in the input.
`<td class=\'postac\'>([A-Z]+[^>]*)<\/td>` is a better solution that handles multiple elements on one line.