# How to remove all numbers from string?

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to remove all numbers from a string [0-9]. I wrote this code that is working:

```
$words = preg_replace('/0/', '', $words ); // remove numbers
$words = preg_replace('/1/', '', $words ); // remove numbers
$words = preg_replace('/2/', '', $words ); // remove numbers
$words = preg_replace('/3/', '', $words ); // remove numbers
$words = preg_replace('/4/', '', $words ); // remove numbers
$words = preg_replace('/5/', '', $words ); // remove numbers
$words = preg_replace('/6/', '', $words ); // remove numbers
$words = preg_replace('/7/', '', $words ); // remove numbers
$words = preg_replace('/8/', '', $words ); // remove numbers
$words = preg_replace('/9/', '', $words ); // remove numbers
```

I'd like to find a more elegant solution: 1 line code (IMO write nice code is important).

The other code I found in stackoverflow also remove the Diacritics (á,ñ,ž...).

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

For Western Arabic numbers (0-9):

```
$words = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $words);
```

For all numerals *including Western Arabic* (e.g. [Indian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numerals)):

```
$words = '१३३७';
$words = preg_replace('/\d+/u', '', $words);
var_dump($words); // string(0) ""
```

- `\d+` matches multiple numerals.
- The modifier `/u` enables unicode string treatment. This modifier is important, otherwise the numerals would not match.

Answer (score 58):

Try with regex `\d`:

```
$words = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $words );
```

`\d` is an equivalent for `[0-9]` which is an equivalent for numbers range from `0` to `9`.

Comment: This is smarter and shorter than the accepted solution, no?

Comment: What you need to know is that \d is all numbers in UTF-8 not only 0123456789 but also that in other languages.

Answer (score 7):

Use Predefined Character Ranges also known as [Character Classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php#128198):

```php
echo $words= preg_replace('/[[:digit:]]/','', $words);
```

Comment: I know I can google it anyhow it would be nice to have in the answer what are PCRs... Does this catch the Western Arabic chars mentioned in other answer?

Comment: You can use the PCR [:nd:] instead of [:digit:]

Answer (score 6):

Use some regex like `[0-9]` or `\d`:

```
$words = preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $words );
```

You might want to read the [preg_replace() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) as this is directly shown there.

Comment: `+` after `\d` is exessive. It's obvious that zero digits cannot be replaced

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
$words = trim($words, " 1..9");
```

Comment: What? Trim only works on the beginning and the end of a string. It would not cover cases like `hello12 world`.

Comment: I agree this unexplained answer is not reliable if a number exists in between two non-numbers.

Answer (score -2):

Regex

```
   $words = preg_replace('#[0-9 ]*#', '', $words);
```

Comment: This answer removed numbers and spaces, but the asker does not want that behavior and never asked for it.