# How to remove contact number in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, mobile

HI I have creating a mobile SMS apps

User can get message in his/her mobile through SMS.

I have 5000 messages in my database. But some messages have contact number

See below message:

```
Success Is Not Permanent & Failure Is Not Final. So,
Never Stop Working After Success & Never Stop Trying After Failure...
1234567890
```

OR

```
Success Is Not Permanent & Failure Is Not Final.
01234567890
So, Never Stop Working After Success & Never Stop Trying After Failure...
```

OR

```
+911234567890 Success Is Not Permanent & Failure Is Not Final. So,
Never Stop Working After Success & Never Stop Trying After Failure...
```

I want to `remove` or `get` contact number in above 3 format `1234567890` `01234567890` `+911234567890`

Comment: `$mystring = preg_replace('/\+?\d{9,11}/','',$mystring);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236148/remove-numbers-from-string-elegant-solution

Comment: The code in @MarkBaker comment seems to leave the final 0 on the third example you provide. It also removes any + symbols. So if a message said "beer + burger is happiness" you would lose the +. As suggested by  Marcins answer below, it's the last line that is the issue. Just explode the string by ... and keep the first array chunk, then update the fields.

Comment: Yes, I miscounted the number of digits in the number; but it certainly shouldn't remove a `+` unless followed by a number

Comment: @TheHumbleRat: This should solve that issue: `/(?:\+\d)?\d{9,12}/`. See demo: http://regex101.com/r/vP9gB4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a one-off procedure run a query (pseudo code)

```
SELECT id,message FROM messages

while query $row

$regex = '/\+?\d{9,13}/';

$insertString = preg_replace($regex,'',$row['message']);

UPDATE Messages
SET message = $insertString
WHERE id = $row['id']
LIMIT 1;

end while
```

Obviously this won't work above but it gives you the code structure and regex you need to achieve your task.

`LIMIT 1` is important!

Don't forget to back-up your database before you do this!

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is always last line of the message, so just remove last line.

Comment: No anywhere is showing. It may be first line or last line...