# PHP remove numbers only

Tags: php, str-replace

Lets say I have a word like this `"I shoot someone using ak47 and m4s 32 times"`
What is the best way to remove pure number number so that I only get `"I shoot someone using ak47 and m4s times"`
I will be really glad if someone can teach me how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all numbers from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236148/how-to-remove-all-numbers-from-string)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, he tries to remove only pure numbers, not numbers with text like ak47 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that with a regex checking for word boundaries and digits:

```
/\b\d+\b/
```

Here you are checking for a word-boundary, followed by any number of digits followed by another word boundary. The forward slashes are the delimiters.

Then you can use for example `preg_replace` to replaced the matched numbers with an empty string:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\b\d+\b/', '', $your_string);
```

Note that you will end up with 2 spaces between `m4s` and `times` but you will not see that in html output. If necessary, you can search for these as well.

Comment: sorry,i try your advice but i got this error message "preg_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given"

Comment: Then you did something wrong, post your whole statement here

Comment: @RyanArief Have you added the second parameter, an empty string?

Comment: What if there are more than 1 instance of a number to remove?

Comment: @Jon No problem, it replaces all the matched combinations.

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_numbers($string) {
    $num = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    return str_replace($num, null, $string);
}
```

Comment: You could use [range](http://php.net/range) (i.e. `range(0, 9)`) rather than using a hardcoded array.