# regex remove number between line breaks

Tags: php, regex

I have a huge code that has numbers between some lines:
eg:

```
code code code
7362
code code code
code code code
code code code
63
code code code
...
```

I want to remove this numbers, between code to become:

```
code code code
code code code
code code code
code code code
code code code
```

I tried:

```
$a = preg_replace("/(s[0-9,]+s)/", "", $a);
```

but it is not working.

```
/(s[0-9,]+s
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14236162/3164682

Answer (score 1):

You forget to escape 's'

```
$a = preg_replace("/(\s[0-9,]+\s)/", "", $a);
```

And coma after 9 is not necessary.

Comment: However, this `\s[0-9,]+\s` will remove line breaks and won't find numbers at the start/end of the string. Actually, this will remove numbers anywhere, not just number-only strings.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to remove digit-only *lines* is to use

```
'~^\d+$\R*~m'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xE5wG5/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of line (since `~m` MULTILINE modifier enables `^` to match the start of a line, not string)
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of line
- `\R*` - zero or more line breaks (any sequence like LF, CR, CR+LF).

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/g9bbeV):

```
$str = "code code code\n7362\ncode code code\ncode code code\ncode code code\n63\ncode code code\n..."; 
$result = preg_replace('~^\d+$\R*~m', '', $str);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score -1):

This will remove all digits:

```
$words = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $words);
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this its working for me.

```
/[1-9][0-9]*/g
```