# extracting string with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have strings containing dash - characters, I want to extract the portion of the string before the first dash character is encountered *except* in the case where the dash is in single/double quotes.

ie.

**Theory 'Gabe B - Tailor' Jacket - nordstrom.com**
I want to extract **Theory 'Gabe B - Tailor' Jacket**

**Theory "Gabe B - Tailor" Jacket - nordstrom.com**
I want to extract **Theory "Gabe B - Tailor" Jacket**

**Tailor Jacket - Jackets - nordstrom.com**
I want to extract **Tailor Jacket**

What regex can I use with preg_match to achieve the result?

Comment: something like `(.*?) - nordstrom.com`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to extract the portion of the string before the *last* dash?

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: Googling tip: You didn't find anything due to your expressionless question [title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/112966#112966). If you entered "regex match text between quotes", you would have; dozens of results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expression like this to handle single and double quoting (without escapes):

```
(?:[^-]+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+
```

Or just capture everything till the last `-`:

```
(.+)-
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a non-regex alternative?

```
$input = "'Gabe B - Tailor' Jacket - nordstrom.com";

$insideQuotes = false;
for ($i=0 ; $i<strlen($input) ; $i++) {

    if (!$insideQuotes && $input[$i] == "-") {
        break;
    }

    if ($input[$i] == "'" || $input[$i] == '"') {
        $insideQuotes = !$insideQuotes;
        continue;
    }
}

echo substr($input, 0, $i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this regexp is what you're looking for -

```
([^-"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?(?=\s*\-)
```