# preg_split values between specific tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Good day.

I'm having a problem with **a pattern**.

Let's assume I have a string like this:

> Hello [person]Name[/person], I don't know regex like
>   [person]Another_name[/person] does.

I need to `preg_split` this string to get an array like this:

```
Array(0 => 'Name', 1 => 'Another_name');
```

I've been trying to solve this for some time and still no luck.

Pardon for my ignorance. Any kind of help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: Use preg_match_all instead of preg_split.

Comment: Can we assume that there will never be any variation in the syntax of `[person]` (ie it will always look as shown in the question; no additional attributes or anything like that), and that there will be no possibility of nested tags? If we can assume that, it's not too hard.

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: thanks a lot! solution was to use preg_match_all instead of preg_split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use something like `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_split`:

```
preg_match_all("|\[person\](.*)\[/person\]|U",
    "Hello [person]Name[/person], I don't know regex like [person]Another_name[/person] does.",
    $out);

echo $out[1][0] . ", " . $out[1][1] . "\n";
```

You can learn more about how `$out` is structured here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php