# preg_match and regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get website adresses from a webpage. The pattern is always:

```
    <br />i <a href="http://www.website.com"
```

The part I need is www.website.com. After reading a lot I made this;

```
    "preg_match('@^(?:<br />i <a href="http://)?([^/]+)@i' , $html, $matches);"
```

but I think I made a mistake...  Someone who can help me ?

I've put my "solution" between brackets because stackoverflow makes a mess of it...

Comment: The `^` anchor means start of subject. * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, but I found this solution after reading these manuals for several hours...And it still doesn't work..

Comment: i'm not skilled with regex, to do something like this I'd try with a html parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match( '/<br \/>i <a href="http:\/\/([^"]+)"/', $html, $matches );
```

Comment: This saves nothing...  Maybe because the ? is missing ?  I tried also preg_match('/<br \/>i <a href="http:\/\/)?([^"]+)'/, $html, $matches );  but still no result...

Comment: Worked when i try it myself. Here is the test case: http://goo.gl/ic7lR Maybe something else is wrong with your code?

Comment: Thank you! You are right. It started to complain about Undefined offset...  But that is right if there are no matches ;-)