# Php regex - remove anything between $ and line break but leave the break

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Okay, I have a php loop that generates a string like this:

```
$string = "1st fee - $500.00<BR>
           2nd fee - $500.00<BR>
           3rd fee - $750.00<BR>"
```

I'd like to remove the dollar amount but I'm not sure it's even possible. I've been trying to use preg_replace to remove everything between `$` and `<` including the `$` but not the `<` to get something like this:

```
   $string = "1st fee - <BR>
               2nd fee - <BR>
               3rd fee - <BR>"
```

Unfortunately for me, I have to leave the `-` because sometimes there will be multiple instances of the `-` on a single line like so:

```
$string = "1st fee - Brian - $500.00<BR>
           2nd fee - John - $500.00<BR>
           3rd fee - Bob - $750.00<BR>"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just telling me give up, not possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What regex did you try? What was the result?
 * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: if `<br>` is supposed to be a break tag, it's deprecated. Use `<br />`

Comment: @PRPGFerret What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: preg_replace('/\$[^<]*/', '', $text)

Comment: why not edit the loop that generates the sting in the first place?

Comment: @Kolink the <BR> in the string, if that's a break tag it's a deprecated tag.

Comment: `<br>` is a tag that has no closing tag, just like `<link>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<hr>` and so on. The XHTML self-closing syntax is frequently used for clarity (to avoid confusion) but is in no way required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you just want to match everyhing from `- $` until the first left arrow in the `<br>`. The first part of the pattern `- \\$` (need to escape the $ since that is a regex keyword) will match the beginning part of what you want removed, and then `[^<]*` will take everything until it finds a left arrow.

```
$string = "1st fee - Brian - $500.00<BR>
           2nd fee - John - $500.00<BR>
           3rd fee - Bob - $750.00<BR>";

$replaced = preg_replace("# - \\$[^<]*#", "", $string);
```

Output:

```
string '1st fee - Brian<BR>
        2nd fee - John<BR>
        3rd fee - Bob<BR>'
```

Comment: @mario Missing third parameter ;)

Comment: Alright alright, I'm pretty bad at explaining regular expressions, but I added in a few details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example to remove the amounts **and the last -**

```
<?php

$string = "1st fee - $500.00<BR>
           2nd fee - $500.00<BR>
           3rd fee - Bob - $750.00<BR>";

$pattern = '/\- \$[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\<BR>$/m';

echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```

Note that because of the `/m` modifier the pattern matches multiple lines, where the `$` ( at the end of the pattern) matches the end of a line. This way it is possible to match every line from right to left and remove the amount and only the last `-` in it.

Comment: preg_replace replace all matching pattern, you don't need /m modifier

Comment: Have you read my post? Of course I need it. Thats the final trick in my example. Note that, currently my example is the only that matches correctly: **- $000.00<BR>\n**

Comment: @Code-Source If you do not understand a post. Please do not downvote it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the full format.
You want to replace an amount so you should use a regexp that correspond to an amount.

```
$reg = '/ - \$[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}/';
$withoutAmount = preg_replace($reg, '', $string);
```

You can improve the regexp with other currencies:

```
$reg = '/ - (\$|£|€)[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}/':
```

To test it:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/auw-gb4