# Parse Twitter Hashtags with Umlauts and stop before point?

Tags: php, regex

I want to regex the Twitter Hashtags. With this Code:

```
    $html = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])\#([^ \"\t\n\r<]*)#ise", "'\\1<a    href=\"".$website_content_url."/search=%23\\2\" target=\"_self\">#\\2</a>'", $html);
```

Everything works fine! But when i use this Word: #Männer! The Link will include the !. But i would like that the Link stops before the ! and other signs that i can enter like the ? or Dot. But the ! should be still displayed ;)

Is that possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you understand how the expression works? It's very easy to extend it to match your requirements. I suggest you spend some time to learn what it does. It's worth more than just copying the solution from somewhere.

Comment: No, i dont understand that^^ It would be great if you tell me how this works! But please note that i need the german umlauts to work too. Thanks :)

Comment: I know you are right Felix! But right now i have not so much time and this is the only thing i need, it would be great if you tell me how this works! And i promise when i have more time i will learn that by myself :)

Comment: So you really ask people to invest time into explaining something to you in detail just because you do not want to invest time into understanding? Go back to 'Start' and _try_ to think before making a move.

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: I dont know where the problem is. I thought i get help here, but it looks like i dont get it here. I asked if someone could explane it to me. If you dont know how something works you ask here too right? Thanks for nothing!!!

Comment: Thanks Mario! But i have not the Time to learn all this, but Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets focus on the interesting part:

```
\#([^ \"\t\n\r<]*)
```

This pattern works as follows:

```
\#          // match #
(           // open a capture group
  [^...]    // a negated character class which matches any character 
            // that is **not** inside this class
  *         // match the previous group / class zero or more times
)           // close capture group
```

Inside the character class, you have `\"\t\n\r<` which means `[^ \"\t\n\r<]` matches any character that is **not** a space, quotation mark, tab, line feed, carriage return or `<`. All you have to do is add the punctuation characters to the class, for example: `[^ \"\t\n\r<!]`.

You don't have to do anything special for umlauts afaik.

---

Good starting point for learning regular expressions: http://regular-expression.info/.

Comment: Thanks you really much Felix!!! I know its better to learn this, but i really have not the Time right now to learn regular expressions. As i promised i will learn that in the feature :) Thanks :)