# Regular Expression to determine if a char is prefixed by number

Tags: php, regex

I have a text link

```
Yeast-Aid™ 200c - Hypoallergenic
```

I want to replace "200c" with "200 Caps" as this will be  done on 20K records i want and expression to be able to replace any "c" prefixed by number  with " Caps".

I use PHP.

Comment: That's easy. Did you attempt anything?
 * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very basic regex substitution. Try this program out:

```
<?php
$string = 'Yeasties 200c - Hyperhyperhyper';
echo preg_replace('/(\d)c/i', '$1 Caps', $string);
echo "\n";
?>
```

`preg_replace` preforms the regex substitution.

If you cannot figure out how that program works, or want a reference, try the php documentation here, [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

You really should look online for documentation first. I have never used php before (literally this is my first program with it), but I didn't find it to challenging. Perhaps the most important coding skill is being able to learn things quickly.