# PHP Regex - ignore exactly 4 or more spaces at the beginning of a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex rule:

```
'/((f|ht)tp)(.*?)(.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg)/'
```

It works great, but I don't want it to match anything that is preceded by a newline and 4 or more spaces, that means something like this:

```
"\n    "
```

How can do this?

Comment: Yeah, like those ``code`` parts here on Stack, where if you start a line with 4 or more spaces, it becomes a code and isn't processed.

Comment: Negative assertions `(?<!...)`.
 * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: @mario Note that assertions with `<` in them (`(?<=...)` and `(?<=...)` are lookbehind assertions and probably not really what is needed here.  Here lookahead assertions `(?=...)` and `(?!...)` are more appropriate (specifically the negative lookahead `(?!...)` in this case).

Comment: Negative lookbehind would be best here if regex in PHP supported variable length lookbehinds.  The regex would be `/(?<!\n {4,}).../` where `...` is the existing regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the linefeed itself in the lookahead, just use the start anchor (`^`) in multiline mode.  Also, since `\s` can match all kinds of whitespace including linefeeds and tabs, you're better off using a literal space character:

```
'/^(?! {4}).*(f|ht)tp(.*?)(.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg)/m'
```

Speaking of tabs, they can be used in place of the four spaces to create code blocks here on SO, so you might want to allow for that as well:

```
'/^(?! {4}|\t).*(f|ht)tp(.*?)(.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg)/m'
```

Finally, if you want the regex to match (as in *consume*) only the URL, you can use the match-start-reset operator, `\K`.  It acts like a positive lookbehind, without the fixed-length limitation:

```
'/^(?! {4}|\t).*?\K(f|ht)tp(.*?)(.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg)/m'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added a negative lookahead anchored at the beginning of the line. It checks for the existence of a newline character followed by 4 or more whitespace characters.  If this condition exists the match will fail.

```
'/^(?!\n\s{4,}).*((f|ht)tp)(.*?)(.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg)/'
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesn't seem to work (the match passes), but I might be doing something wrong, although I'd say I'm not.

Comment: @RichardRodriguez Yeah just did a little testing and it seems I am able to get it to work when moving the line start anchor outside of the lookahead (not sure why it didn't work inside).  Take a look at the revised answer.