# PHP Explode Words

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP programming. I need your help to finish my homework.

I want to explode the following sentence: **I love my band and my cat** into arrays.

But I need to use **space** and word **and** as delimiters. So it should become like this:

```
$arr[0] -> I
$arr[1] -> love
$arr[2] -> my
$arr[3] -> band
$arr[4] -> my
$arr[5] -> cat
```

I have tried like this:

```
$words = "I love my band and my cat"
$stopwords = "/ |and/";
$arr = explode($stopwords, $words);
```

But the problem is, it also removes characters **and** from word **band** so it becomes like this:

```
$arr[0] -> I
$arr[1] -> love
$arr[2] -> my
$arr[3] -> b
$arr[4] -> my
$arr[5] -> cat
```

This is not what I want. I want to remove the word that exactly **and**, not word that contains **and** characters.

Is there anyway to solve this? Can anybody help me? Thank you very much.. :-)

Comment: `explode` is for fixed strings. `split` and `preg_split` are for regexpressions like you tried.

Comment: Since you've admitted this is homework I feel I cannot give you the answer. But i suggest you read this http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html. also, use preg_split, explode can't use regular expressions.

Comment: If the task is not about regex, a logic is to explode it first and then remove (unset) the unneeded elements.

Comment: One way to look at the problem you are having is to think about what is different with `and` and `band`. Specifically whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid splitting out `and` in the middle of a word, you have to filter the result list (`array_diff`), or use a more complex regex. Then also consider `preg_match_all` instead of splitting:

```
 preg_match_all('/  (?! \b and \b)  (\b \w+ \b)  /x', $input, $words);
```

This will only search for consecutive word-characters, instead of breaking up on spaces. And the assertion `?!` will skip occurences of `and`.

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
<?php
$words = "I love my band and my cat";
$clean = str_replace(" and",'',$words);
$array = explode(" ",$clean);
print_r($array);
?>
```

Comment: he needs to remove the word and from the array

Comment: Until he needs to use "and also my dog" as the string

Comment: @ChrisK Agreed, but it accomplishes the task to spec.

Comment: What happens when the string is "i am going to visit andrew tomorrow"?